# \$n\$ swaps into a nop

Tags: code-golf, array

Given \$n, m\ge 1\$. There are \$n\$ balls. Do \$m\$ moves, each choose a ball (maybe also the first one), and exchange with the one currently on the first place. At the end, the order of balls should be the same as the initial state.

You can either output all possibilities, or a random one provided all possibilities have non-zero probability to be outputted. You can use 0-index or 1-index. You can output a specific ball either by its initial position or by its position at the time of that move. Shortest code win.

Tests: (1-index, current position)

```
n=9, m=1 => 1
n=4, m=2 => 1,1; 2,2; 3,3; 4,4
n=2, m=3 => 1,1,1; 1,2,2; 2,1,2; 2,2,1
```

For case 1, with only 1 move we can't do any actual swap but swapping with itself. For case 2, we can swap the first ball to anywhere but the next step we have to make it back.

Comment: I've tried to clean up the explanation a bit, specifically the part about using the initial position vs. the current position since that took me a couple of tries to understand. Please let me know if I've deviated from your intent or changed the meaning on anything. Looks like a very fun challenge though!

Comment: Isn’t m times 1 a trivial solution in every case? This simplifies this challenge to: given m, n: output m time a “1”.

Comment: @agtoever all possibilities have non-zero probability to be outputted if you only output one

Comment: @l4m2 : ah. Ok. Missed that part. You are correct. Thanks.

Comment: It would be very nice to see an approach to this motivated by [tag:abstract-algebra].  Since these are permutations they of course form a group, and further more the group is always abelian.

Comment: @WheatWitch The set of swap-with-1st-position-permutations is not a group, since it's not closed under composition, but they do generate the symmetric group of \$\{1,...,n\}\$. This group is not abelian, either: for an initial state of `123`, swapping positions 1 and 2, then positions 1 and 3 results in `312`, but doing that in the reverse order results in `231`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>20</s>  19 bytes

<sup>There is probably* a terser way to swap the items...</sup>

```
’RŒBF!‘œ?@ƒ⁹Ƒ
ṗçƇR{
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the number of balls, \$n\$, on the left and the number of moves, \$m\$, on the right and yields a list of lists of valid move sequences using 0-indexing.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS4A0f9qZWxsef//4oCZUsWSQkYh4oCYxZM/QMaS4oG5xpEK4bmXw6fGh1J7////NP82)**

#### How?

Filters all length \$m\$ potential instructions consisting of the alphabet \$[1,n]\$ keeping those which cause no change when applied.

In order to perform a single instructed swap the code translates this to an equivalent sequence of swaps of adjacent elements. The swaps are then applied in turn starting with an ordered list where the rightmost element is the first index and the leftmost is the last.

To swap the \$k^{\text{th}}\$ element with the \$1^{\text{st}}\$ we actually perform multiple swaps of neighbouting pairs, first to move the \$1^{\text{st}}\$ element to position \$k\$ and then to move the original \$k^{\text{th}}\$ element to to position \$1\$

For example starting with elements `GFEDCBA` (A being the "first") to swap the sixth element (`F`) with the first (`A`) we swap like so:

```
(indices):  7654321
    start:  GFEDCBA  moving A from index 1...
swap(2,1):  GFEDCAB  .
swap(3,2):  GFEDACB  .
swap(4,3):  GFEADCB  .
swap(5,4):  GFAEDCB  .
swap(6,5):  GAFEDCB  done, now moving F to index 1...
swap(5,4):  GAEFDCB  .
swap(4,3):  GAEDFCB  .
swap(3,2):  GAEDCFB  .
swap(2,1):  GAEDCBF  done.
```

This is then performed by noting that `swap(n,n-1)` can be performed by calculating the \$((n-1)!+1)^{\text{th}}\$ lexicographical permutation of the current state (which I wrote a built-in for a few years ago, `œ?`).

```
’RŒBF!‘œ?@ƒ⁹Ƒ - Link, is transform an invariant?: instruction string, [1..n]
’             - decrement (each instruction) e.g. [4,1,3] -> [3,0,2]
 R            - range                        -> [[1,2,3],[],[1,2]]
  ŒB          - bounce                       -> [[1,2,3,2,1],[],[1,2,1]]
    F         - flatten                      -> [1,2,3,2,1,1,2,1]
     !        - factorial                    -> [1,2,6,2,1,1,2,1]
      ‘       - increment                    -> [2,3,6,3,2,2,3,2]
                -> this is an equivalent set of instructions swapping neighbouring pairs in
                   turn, as lexicographical permutation indices.
           ⁹  - right argument = [1..n]
            Ƒ - is invariant under?:
          ƒ   -   apply the new instructions to [1..n] in turn using:
       œ?@    -     nth index-lexicographical permutation

ṗçƇR{ - Main Link: n, m
ṗ     - (n) Cartesian power (m) -> all length m strings of alphabet [1..m]
   R{ - range (n) -> [1..n]
  Ƈ   - filter (the strings) keeping those for which:
 ç    -   call last Link (1) as a dyad, f(potential_string, [1..n])
```

---

* Although this is 20:

```
J=o⁸ɗḊ⁹;ị⁸
ṗçƒ⁹Ƒ¥ƇR{
```

<sup>10 bytes to swap to list elements by index; perhaps Jelly should have a `œ.` built-in to swap elements of a list by indices?</sup>

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/),  <s>123 120 113</s>  112 bytes

Expects `(n)(m)`. Prints all 0-indexed solutions.

```javascript
n=>g=(m,A=[...Array(n)],o)=>A.some((v,j)=>m?g(m-1,A,[o]+j+' ',[A[j],A[0],A]=[A[0]^j,v^j,[...A]]):v)|m?0:print(o)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxBCoMwFET3PUV3/o/foLaLKkTJOUIKoTRiIIlECRR69zR2MfPmbcbqpPdXXLejSY9sePZ8Wjg4ElwyxkSM@gMeFQXkk2B7cG@ARLaYmxdwTUeCZFC1ratrRVJIq0jItpTi8hxPS6nk/6YUjgm/bm7HLa7@gIDZwIDQ4cXAHaE/2SPcMP8A)

#### How?

Instead of storing \$[0,1,\dots,n-1]\$ into the reference array, we store the actual value at a given position XOR'ed with the expected value.

This makes the initialization and the final test easier and shorter to write because we start with an array filled with \$0\$'s and expect to end up with the same configuration. (In the JS code, we actually start with an array filled with undefined values and test that there's no truthy value in the final one.)

To exchange \$A_0\$ and \$A_j\$, we do:

$$\cases{A_j\leftarrow A_0\operatorname{xor}j\\
A_0\leftarrow A_j\operatorname{xor}j
}$$

The implementation is a bit freaky. Within a recursive call to \$g\$, we pass the current instance of \$A[\:]\$ and then simultaneously update \$A[0]\$, update \$A[j]\$ and set \$A[\:]\$ to a new instance consisting of a copy of itself before the changes are applied, so that the array is restored to its initial state after the call:

```javascript
g(…, A, …, [A[j], A[0], A] = [A[0] ^ j, v ^ j, [...A]])
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 111 bytes

```hs
(0?y)q=[[]|q==y]
(n?y@(h:t))q=[k:x|k<-q,x<-(n-1)?(y!!(k-1):tail(take(k-1)y++h:drop k y))$q]
x#y=x?[1..y]$[1..y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYhLCsMgEED3OUVCXIykhoZ2JRF7D3EhNKBMamPqwoHc3f5W7@PdC5d1rRXOmnhSxtgjKUW2gajpBl5m/t0oy4GzSKcyC4hi4hqo6wA/JrMLK2SHyy9pGLy878@txZY4Z8k2pSdVtJnGkSz7oz5ciGrbQ8zs0l/rGw)

Just attempts every possible path and returns the ones that work.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 31 bytes

Uses 0-indexing. A lot more complicated than it has to be.

```
L©<Iãʒ®yv¹<!y*¹ÍLRyDĀ-£!O+.I}āQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AToAxf9vc2FiaWX//0zCqTxJw6PKksKueXbCuTwheSrCucONTFJ5RMSALcKjIU8rLkl9xIFR/10@wrv/Mgoz)

This generates all move sequences and selects the right ones by doing the swapping. Instead of directly swapping values (which would probably be shorter), this calculates the index of the permutation that does the right swap.

For a list of length \$t\$ the permutation that swaps the first with the \$n\$-th value has index

$$
(n-1) \cdot (t-1)! \, + \sum_{i=t-n+1}^{t-2} i!
$$

(Uses 1-indexing, Related OEIS sequence: [A211369](https://oeis.org/A211369))

This is calculated by `¹<!y*¹ÍLRyDĀ-£!O+`, where `¹` is \$t\$ and `y` is \$n-1\$. The sum part is quite annoying to compute, because all the range builtins don't want to return empty lists.

```python
                     # Full program, taking two inputs
                     # ¹ the length of the move sequence
                     # ² the number of balls
L©                   # range from 1 to ¹, store in register
  <                  # decrement to get range from 0 to ¹-1
   Iã                # all ²-tuples of numbers in the range
     ʒ               # filter on:
      ®              #   start with the range 1 .. ¹
       yv       }    #   iterate over the current move sequence:
          ...        #     calculate permutation index
              .I     #     apply corresponding permutation
                 āQ  #   is the result equal to [1 .. length]?
```

Comment: Actually swapping them instead of using the permutation is indeed quite a bit shorter: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f59BKG8/Di09NOrSusszFoPJRw6zDKyoNgNTxubVHGgP//zfiMgYA).

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 49 bytes

```
Nest[#/.r&,r={1->#,#->1}&~Array~#,#2]~Position~r&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73y@1uCRaWV@vSE2nyLbaUNdOWUdZ186wVq3OsagosbIOyDWKrQvIL84syczPqytS@x9QlJkH1KJrl@bgoByrVhecnJhXV81VbaljWKvDVW2iYwSijHSMgRSIawLiGuuY1nLV/gcA)

Input `[n, m]`.

Thanks to alephalpha's [now-deleted answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235713/81203) for the idea to swap values instead of positions.

Swapping the positions \$1\$ and \$x\$ of the \$\text{position}\to\text{ball}\$ list is equivalent to swapping the values \$1\$ and \$x\$ of the \$\text{ball}\to\text{position}\$ list.

The list that's being mutated isn't actually `1..n`, but it contains all numbers in the range all the same.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 124 bytes

```python
def f(n,m,*l):
 *p,=*q,=range(n)
 for x in l:q[0],q[x]=q[x],q[0]
 return m and sum([f(n,m-1,*l,i)for i in p],[])or[l][:q==p]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY7BCoQwDETvfkWOiWRh1b2s0C8pPQjqbkFjWyu4X981XjKEmXlM@OXvJl0p4zTDjMIr1wv1FdSBTR3ZpEE@EwpVMG8JTvACSx/t03G0pzN6WN8K0pSPJLDCICPsx4r25j2ai8ietO61HhxbR1uyi7N9NCa4ot4VVRfxzQ0x4ItblZY70j0QkpeMN5Ko/AE)

Brute force search. Outputs all options.

-3 bytes thanks to Jakque

Comment: `[j for i in p for j in f(n,m-1,*l,i)]` =>`sum([f(n,m-1,*l,i)for i in p],[])` saves 3 bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 86 bytes

```ruby
->n,m{w=*0...n;w.product(*[w]*~-m).select{|x|s=*w;x.map{|c|s[0],s[c]=s[c],s[0]};s==w}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYhBCsIwEADvvsKjhu1Say8S1o@EHDS2J1NDt2UrSfx6JIiXYWbm9f4uI5XmOoGPQqpFxEkLhvn1WN1yUEas@jT@iDw8B7fEtCUmJXpDfwsxucSmtcDGWaqAmlkzkeRcwn40FzjZXZUeup90cP6f3pYv)

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 118 bytes

```r
function(n,m,l=expand.grid(rep(list(v<-1:n),m)))l[apply(l,1,function(s){for(i in s)v[c(1,i)]=v[c(i,1)];all(v==1:n)}),]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY27CsMwDAB/JaMEasGQqa2/JHgweRSBIgs7NS0h3@6SDt1uubvcNFnxbXnpuHFSUFpJ/Py2qNP1mXmCPBsIlw3q4@JuirQiogzRTD4g5OjvFtyXlIE71q5gHUZwxBj8SUwOwz2KQPX@zBxI4TeHnnpsXw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 60 bytes

```
≔…⁰ＮθＮη⊞υ⟦⟦⟧θ⟧Ｆυ¿⁼Ｌ§ι⁰ηＦ⁼⊟ιθＩιＦθ⊞υ⟦⁺§ι⁰⟦κ⟧Ｅ§ι¹⎇∧μ⁻κμλ§§ι¹⁻κμ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY9Na8MwDIbv/RU6SuBBP447hdFDoS2h9FZy8Fo3NnWUxB9j@/We2q2Q7SLQo0ev7LPV4dxrX0oVo2sZD5pbg3MFGx5y2ufu3QQkUjDS62zKrPR1jhazgtOpEaERcu0DYCZwV8D1mLWPuDXcJotV2vDFfKJTML/nWSJ42L9a3Q/oHncI6uA44ZuOSZCkGh/NjzzK8Hm09jn@jRV4a6Tu9DAdLAQdTWAdvrDiC3ZiOJblm4Lu/hav4Kn/W5t6RPLDUpawKi8f/hs) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs all 0-indexed possibilities by current position. Explanation:

```
≔…⁰Ｎθ
```

Create the initial range of `n` elements.

```
Ｎη
```

Input `m`.

```
⊞υ⟦⟦⟧θ⟧
```

Start a breadth-first search with a possibility of `0` moves and the initial position.

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop over the possibilities.

```
¿⁼Ｌ§ι⁰η
```

If this possibility has `m` moves, then...

```
Ｆ⁼⊟ιθＩι
```

... print the possibility if the initial state was reached.

```
Ｆθ
```

Otherwise, looping over each position, ...

```
⊞υ⟦⁺§ι⁰⟦κ⟧Ｅ§ι¹⎇∧μ⁻κμλ§§ι¹⁻κμ
```

... push the possibility obtained from the switch to the search list.