# Swap Two Values in a List

Tags: code-golf, number, array, integer

### Introduction:

Although we have a lot of challenges where swapping two items in a list is a subtask, like [Single swaps of an array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/152283/52210); [Swap to Sort an Array](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/197536/52210); [\$n\$ swaps into a nop](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/235710/52210); etc., we don't have the simple challenge of just swapping two items given a list and two indices.

**Input:**
A list with some positive integers \$L\$, and two indices \$a\$ and \$b\$.

**Output:**
The same list, with the two items at the given indices swapped.

### Challenge rules:

- The input-list is guaranteed to contain at least two items.
- The input-list is guaranteed to only contain positive integers.
- The input-indices can be either 0-based or 1-based (please specify in your answer which of the two you've used).
- The input-indices are guaranteed to be valid indices based on the length of the input-list.
- The input-indices are distinct, so will never be the same index. (The values in the input-list won't necessarily be distinct.)
- You can assume \$a<b\$ (and you're allowed to take the inputs in reversed order if it helps).
- I/O is flexible. You're allowed to take the input as a list/array/stream, from STDIN, as a delimited string, etc. You're allowed to modify the input-list directly, or return a new one with the two items swapped.

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (e.g. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases

All test cases use 0-based indices.

```
Inputs: L=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], a=3, b=7
Output:   [1,2,3,8,5,6,7,4,9,10]

Inputs: L=[ 3, 8, 1, 4,10,10,10,10], a=0, b=5
Output:   [10, 8, 1, 4,10, 3,10,10]

Inputs: L=[5,1,4,2,3], a=0, b=4
Output:   [3,1,4,2,5]

Inputs: L=[5,6], a=0, b=1
Output:   [6,5]

Inputs: L=[2,2,2], a=0, b=1
Output:   [2,2,2]
```

Comment: For un-number-input-friendly languages can we take in chars? (Assumed no)

Comment: @null What are you using for the indices if your language of choice doesn't include numbers?

Comment: They probably meant that parsing a number from input is difficult, so they wanted to take input as the byte value of a character code. I think it is pretty common to allow this, but it technically restricts the values (not all of them will restrict to bytes, but there is usually some cap).

Comment: [Duplicate?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/127839/9288)

Comment: @alephalpha Oh.. Apparently it is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swap the two given indices](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/127839/swap-the-two-given-indices)

Comment: @pxeger I think it makes more sense to close that one as a dupe of this one. This has more answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 1 [byte](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
µ
```

Apparently MathGolf has a builtin for this. Came across it in the docs when I was working on another challenge today. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯.

Takes the loose index-inputs before the list.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///Q1v//jRXMFaINdYx0jHVMdEx1zHTMdSx0LHUMDWK5DBRMFaKNgVxDoJShARyBZEwUok3B4kCNIL4hiG8GZRkBRY1iAQ)

Answer (score 15):

## Java, 27 bytes

```java
java.util.Collections::swap
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU/BTsMwDL33K3xMJRMxBgzWDQkhTUKC046IQ@iSKl2aVrE7NE399pKugyF4F8vPfs/Ppdqpi3Kz7W3V1IGhjL1s2Tr5Yomz5B/9GILaU5Y07YezOeROEcGrsh4OCURYzzoYlWtYHXa13YARg9PiOfKFDg/gYofDGtixlGnWHaUnS2LFsRzFVTQWaw7WF2/voEJB6XhmwArMsj8ne6qd0znb2tN8Tp@q6b8Xsx/JnyiwhPEfqWgYiQle4RSv8QZvcYZ3eI@Ty/QsN9IIhzBFmP1i13tiXcm6ZdnEpOy8cKdxl3T9Fw)

Comment: Huh, something actually has a builtin for this. A little on the long side, but I guess a lambda would be longer still.

Comment: @Neil A lambda without using the builtin would be 31 bytes: `(a,i,j)->a[i]^=a[j]^(a[j]=a[i])`

Comment: Hmm, in JShell `java.util.*` is imported by default. I wonder if you can leverage that by calling your language Java+JShell?

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 32 bytes

```
def f(a,b,l):l[a],l[b]=l[b],l[a]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWNxVSUtMU0jQSdZJ0cjStcqITY3VyopNibUGEDogLVaeWY5uZV1BaoqHJlaYBZenA6BxNroKizLwShRyI6gU7o411LHQMdUx0DA3gKJbLgMsUogAA)

Mutates the input in-place.

---

26 bytes with a [NumPy](https://numpy.org) array:

```python
def f(l,a):l[a[::-1]]=l[a]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYtLCgMhEAX3fQqXCh0YJwkEYU4ivRAmEsFP0zgLT28@DIGCqrd4PPqr1XXO/RlV1BmDcdkH79zFEm2fpBmlFVWPwkOlwk26CiJhQN5@1qny0bUx8P37c@FpMsCSald5@is@0OIN7fKHYIE7vAE)

Comment: Blazingly fast 2!

Comment: You're allowed to modify the input-list, so [32 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PyU1TSFNI1EnSSdH0yonOjFWJyc6KdYWROiAuP9zbKMNdYx0jHVMdEx1zHTMdSx0LHUMDWK50jSMgbwcTa6Cosy8Eo0czf8A) is possible with this approach.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen thanks!

Comment: The solution isn't specific to python 2 btw — it [works just as well in python 3](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/PyU1TSFNI1EnSSdH0yonOjFWJyc6KdYWROiAuP99bKONdSx0DHVMdAwN4CiWK9HWgCvJ1pQLpFkhSUfBR5OroCgzr0TDR/M/FwA)

Comment: @AlexWaygood It's in Python 2 here because [originally](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/posts/236304/revisions#rev-body-c56fe6c3-9264-42d2-a4a8-9134e5089cc7) it had `;print l`, which was shorter  in 2 than 3

Answer (score 9):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/Flakheads/BrainHack), 122 bytes

```
(([{}]{()<({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)>}{})<(({}({}))([{}]{})<{({}()<<>({}<>)>)}{}>)>())<>({}<<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}>){<>({}<>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYw7CoBADAWvk1f6K4SQiyxbqI0iWNiGPfsz62IlBIYMk6z3clz7sp2kSPKSXaDiJQlypRrUDFa8hA8RA7QyjFcDVWupIbqAAE2p@f/Z2/h3ExvJniNndsGBE6cH)

## Works with all integers, 138 bytes

```
(([{}]{()<({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)>}{})<(({}({}))([{}]{})<{({}()<<>({}<>)>)}{}>)>())<>({}<<>{({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}{}>)<>([]){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYw7CoBADESvkyn9FULIRZYt1EYRLGzDnj3OuqVCYIY3j6z3clz7sp0RIslLdoGKlyTINdWgZrDihZyABzSTxCuBqjXVQI8hQENq/n32OtxTxt@qFhF9jDFHxxzYpgc)

The difference here is that while the first uses

```
{<>({}<>)}{}
```

To pull all the items from the off stack onto the on stack this one has to use

```
<>({}){({}[()]<({}<>)<>>)}<>
```

The first one pulls until it hits a zero and then stops, so this will fail to produce the correct result when there is a zero before the first swapped value.  The second checks the height and pulls that many times, thus it will work for any list.

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 bytes

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/)>=4.1, 24 bytes** by replacing the word `function` with `\`.

```r
function(L,A){L[A]=L[rev(A)];L}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fYuxCsIwFEX3fsUDlxd8Q5M0VSoZsgf8gJBBgwGXKiVxEb891lJLQRDucOGcM5SoS8x9SNdbj5YMe1pnvLZuuDzQMH@wrxKRd7ymgJJ2bMtZFfHzYU/ACRoa2XeMIOBJ1wRnrRZXEaeGBMk1bia8OeZ0z6kDACdnTflqztp1wH@CdlHFmIn/8qT48gY)

Takes input as a vector and a vector of two `1`-based indices.

Answer (score 7):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 21 bytes

```
[ [ exchange ] keep ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dcw9DoIwAIbhnVO8JzAiKqgHMC4uxokwNM3nT2xKLSXBGM9eGZ/luRmb@pivl9P5uGfQe5S3GngpejlCVEqfEJ8@cSiKipovJSsq1mzYzm7YUS755ZYWTfZh/F1086BAl61xjkX@Aw)

It's almost a built-in, but `exchange` has stack effect `( m n seq -- )` so we need `keep` to actually keep the sequence around on the data stack. 0-indexed.

Answer (score 7):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 11 bytes

```rust
<[_]>::swap
```

Modify the input in-place.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcpLCoMwAEXReVbxdFAivEHtzzax7UJEihQDQgyisQ7EtaeS6bl3nCcfjEPfdE5mq7Cth8EToaw@9UupaWmGoCP3s4fd06/9JlVOnIgzcSGuxI0oiDvxIPJjrYWRh/jHp8i0GMbOeesSma7qvaWE3XELfw)

Comment: shortest non-golfing language so far, isn't it?

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>7</s> 5 bytes

```
œPżịF
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5ICjex7u7nb7H/qoYcbh5UpHJz3cOeNR05rI//@jjXUUzGN1FKINdBRMobQJlDaE0/@jDXWMdIx1THRMdcx0zHUsdCx1DA1A0gpA/RZAJUBdQBE4AkmZ6hgCNQC1QThmIMoIyDeKBQA)

Takes indexes as 1 indexed and reversed (so `[b, a]`), the Footer on TIO does this for you.

### How it works

```
œPżịF - Main link. Takes indices I on the left, array A on the right
œP    - Partition A at the indices in I, not keeping the borders
   ị  - Retrieve the elements of A at the indices in I; [A[b], A[a]]
  ż   - Zip together
    F - Flatten
```

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)

1-indexed. Reverse the sublist at the indices given by the second input of the first input.

```apl
⌽@⎕⊢⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKM97f@jnr0Oj/qmPupaBCRBQv/TuB71blYwNOAyUbDgSuMyVrBQMFQwAQrAEZehghkA)

Answer (score 6):

## Lean, <s>211</s> 205 bytes

Helper:

```
notation `L`:=list ℕ
structure R:=m::(A:L)(B:ℕ)(C:L)
def r:L->L->ℕ->R
|p(h::t)0:=R.m p h t
|p(h::t)(n+1):=r(p++[h])t n
|_[]_:=R.m[]0[]
```

Actual function:

```
λl a b,let f:=r[]l a,z:=r[]f.C(b-a-1)in f.A++z.B::z.A++f.B::z.C
```

[Try it online!](https://leanprover-community.github.io/lean-web-editor/#code=import%20data.list.basic%0Aimport%20data.nat.basic%0A%0Anotation%20%60L%60%3A%3Dlist%20%E2%84%95%0Astructure%20R%3A%3Dm%3A%3A%28A%3AL%29%28B%3A%E2%84%95%29%28C%3AL%29%0Adef%20r%3AL-%3EL-%3E%E2%84%95-%3ER%0A%7Cp%28h%3A%3At%290%3A%3DR.m%20p%20h%20t%0A%7Cp%28h%3A%3At%29%28n%2B1%29%3A%3Dr%28p%2B%2B%5Bh%5D%29t%20n%0A%7C_%5B%5D_%3A%3DR.m%5B%5D0%5B%5D%0Adef%20s%20%3A%20list%20%E2%84%95%20-%3E%20%E2%84%95%20-%3E%20%E2%84%95%20-%3E%20list%20%E2%84%95%20%3A%3D%0A%CE%BBl%20a%20b%2Clet%20f%3A%3Dr%5B%5Dl%20a%2Cz%3A%3Dr%5B%5Df.C%28b-a-1%29in%20f.A%2B%2Bz.B%3A%3Az.A%2B%2Bf.B%3A%3Az.C%0A%0A%23eval%20s%20%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D%203%207%0A--%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C8%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C4%2C9%2C10%5D%0A%0A%23eval%20s%20%5B%203%2C%208%2C%201%2C%204%2C10%2C10%2C10%2C10%5D%200%205%0A--%5B10%2C%208%2C%201%2C%204%2C10%2C%203%2C10%2C10%5D%0A%0A%23eval%20s%20%5B5%2C1%2C4%2C2%2C3%5D%200%204%0A--%5B3%2C1%2C4%2C2%2C5%5D%0A%0A%23eval%20s%20%5B5%2C6%5D%200%201%0A--%5B6%2C5%5D%0A%0A%23eval%20s%20%5B2%2C2%2C2%5D%200%201%0A--%5B2%2C2%2C2%5D)

There's got to be a way to make product types and define type aliases easily, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage), 7 bytes

```
,U$yJ}ị
```

[Try It Online!](https://jht.hyper-neutrino.xyz/tio#WyIiLCIsVSR5Sn3hu4siLCIiLCIiLFsiMSwgNiIsIlsgMywgOCwgMSwgNCwxMCwxMCwxMCwxMF0iXV0=)

A totally different Jelly 7-byter, so I figured I'd post this too. This is 1-indexed.

```
,U$yJ}ị    Main link; take indices on the left
,U$        Pair the indices with the reverse of itself ([[a, b], [b, a]])
   y       Apply this as a translation to
    J}     The indices of the right list (J takes a list of length L and returns [1, 2, ..., L])
      ị    Index back into the original list
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 56 bytes

```hs
(?)=splitAt
(x!y)z|(q,d:e)<-y?z,(a,b:c)<-x?q=a++d:c++b:e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/X8Ne07a4ICezxLGES6NCsVKzqkajUCfFKlXTRrfSvkpHI1EnySoZyKmwL7RN1NZOsUrW1k6ySv2fm5iZZ5uSz6VQUJSZV6JiqGikEm2oY6RjrGMSCxM0UDQGCurpGRrE/gcA)

`splitAt` breaks the list into two parts at the particular index.  This is useful because unlike `(!!)` we can get all the parts first.

To start we split at the second element, then the first.  Splitting at the second first means we don't have to do extra arithmetic do calculate the offset which is required if we split at the first.

We use a pattern match to then get the first element of various pieces.

Comment: Blazingly fast!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, 31 bytes

```js
l=>a=>b=>l[a]^=l[b]^(l[b]=l[a])
```

Only works for integers.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYlNCoAgFAb3nUThC/rXFs@LiMIzEAqJKPH6VpuBmTm48LPd@5XbomukmsgwmUAmWXaekg3Oi5/0B/l922PAiAkzFihorOg7B6YRgVQTRZKCpQiyue79zJ/WFw)

*Thanks to [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563).*

## JavaScript, 32 bytes

```js
l=>a=>b=>[l[a],l[b]]=[l[b],l[a]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYpLCoAwEMX2nqSFJ/j/LKYXGWYxFQSlSKnS61ddhYScmvXe0hGfOi9lpxLIKTlPjgOrILAXIf6BP8g3cIsOPQaMmDBjwYq2ESj18DRXuwnWqDXeVjEd1/NpeQE)

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 20 bytes

```julia
L*i=L[i]=L[i[[2,1]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY5NbsMgEIX3nGKWkI4i4784C25AT4BYEGWkUiHLcpw2t3fHxknkXRFC8973HvB9TzHoxzzbQzTWRb8czpWovffz71dMBNN4JwG8LAa8gAH6CUl@0hSOQxhvJEcK1xR7kkqpNUiP4T@xt7HK8GH0OlyewzDGfkq9lOvLW8seHAu/C1i1l2DM8gklqL/OTmOJFdbYYIsn7PCMuvAIFcJJbLDbYJ2hEG7BHYJGqNl5be4VCA33ih3neOZcbVDzRXxtDtfCVZvTZNxmoIVrs1UyK19mVn8)

1-indexed

expects `L*[a,b]` and mutates `L`

Answer (score 4):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 4 bytes

```
{e\}
```

Code block ([analogous to a function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398)) that pops three elements from the stack: `L`, `a`, `b`, and pushes the swapped version of `L`. Indices `a`, `b` are 0-based.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##S85KzP1fWPe/OjWm9n9dwf9oBWMFCwVDBRMFQwM4ilUwUDAFAA)

#### Explanation

```
{  }  e# Define code block
 e\   e# Swap elements in array
```

*Header:*

```
q     e# Read all input as an unevaluated string, and push it to the stack
 ~    e# Evaluate string. Gives an array and two numbers, that are pushed
```

*Footer:*

```
~     e# Execute block
 p    e# Print string representation of the top of the stack
```

Comment: CJam is winning `\o/`

Comment: Nice to see CJam beating Jelly for a to-the-point challenge like this. :) I'm actually surprised Jelly is 5 bytes. When I prepared my 4-byter 05AB1E program (which I will post if no one else will), I was expecting Jelly to have a 3-byte variant, but apparently not.

Comment: _Apparently not_ only because Dennis is not around :-D

Answer (score 4):

## [stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 5 bytes

```
$exch
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JTM5OTfn/XyW1Ijnjv4NVGheXhoaGoYKRgrGCiYKpgpmCuYKFgqWCoYGmAlDIXJNLQUPDGChkCJQ2NIAjoKyCgYIpWNoULAk0ASSIAAYKJlBpM1QJmLQhWNoIqNNIE6u0JhdXtJ6eXlqsQm5igUJ@acl/AA)

You can remove the `$` if input is allowed to be taken from the stack for 4 bytes. Convenient builtin to be sure.

### [22 bytes](https://tio.run/##bczLCsIwEIXhfZ7iLJNNyKRNq67yHiGLoBZab4FWxKePY/CC4DCr/2NmXtL2sN@VEvzkxzBiwnm@pRxTzsd7LH4zCCGlJFg0aOHQoccKa5BR4NQrASkbTsRM5rOsMHCVXUX@8IzfMWhf3P3Cm6my5Uur/rISImith4hTyrhcl/IA)

```
[@j@i[i j nswap]apply]
```

Function. `nswap` performs a stack operation of swapping the `i`th and `j`th members, so we simply pop `i` and `j` and treat the stack at the top of the stack *as* the stack for `nswap`.

Answer (score 4):

## Kotlin, 34 bytes

```kotlin
{l,x,y->l[x]=l[y].also{l[y]=l[x]}}
```

Ungolfed:

```kotlin
{ l, x, y ->
    l[x] = l[y].also { l[y] = l[x] }
}
```

This answer is a bit of an idiom in Kotlin.

`Any#also()` basically executes the given function, but then returns the receiver. In this case, the outer `l[y]` is evaluated, then `.also()` runs the lambda `{ l[y] = l[x] }`, and returns the old value of `l[y]`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU7BCsIwFLvvK96xhbfhnDoVu7ugePI0dqhgoeytFdfJRtm3120ezCEkIZDU1pE24SMJ1BHYtXPyQc@Lbt3pbFyBMPFCHOIC7kY7EMET9jjEBZV9JagcqkRSa/2sxJyNY1CdgUZqwzh4iGDCPEEgoPlP3BRLcY0ZbnCLO8xxjwdMV3zpK0YIGUL@s/VyNNE2eb21cYx4NIYv)

Answer (score 3):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org), 39 bytes

```
eval "t=$`<i`;`<i`=$`<j`;`<j`=$"t
<<<$@
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwZqM1MQUBV1Du0wuu6ylpSVpuhY31VPLEnMUlEpsVRJsMhOsQQSImQViZgGZSiVcNjY2Kg4Q5Qsg1MZoQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdcx2L2CXGXGZcEEkA)

Takes the array on the command line, with the two indices in files called `i` and `j`.

A bit of quote trickery to avoid escapes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-xp`, 8 bytes

```
aRAba@Rb
```

Takes input as two command-line arguments: the list, and a list containing the two indices (0-based). [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgebSSbkWBUuyCpaUlaboWKxKDHJMSHYKSIFyo6E3laKVoQ2sja2NrE2tTazNrc2sLa0trQ4NYJR0FpWhja_NYuAkA)

#### Explanation

The `-x` flag is for taking the arguments as lists rather than strings; the `-p` flag is for displaying the result as a list rather than concatenated together.

```lisp
a         ; In the first argument
 RA       ; replace the items at indices given by
   b      ; the second argument
    a     ; with the values in the first argument
     @    ; at indices
      Rb  ; reverse(second argument)
```

---

The straightforward version, which takes the indices as separate arguments, comes in at [9 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgebSSbkWBUuyCpaUlaboWKxMdkqysEh2SEyF8qPBNhWilaENrI2tjaxNrU2sza3NrC2tLa0ODWCUdBWMdBXOYfgA):

```lisp
a@b::a@ca
   ::      ; Swap
a@b        ; the item in a at index b
     a@c   ; with the item in a at index c
        a  ; Output the new value of a
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 34 bytes

```c
f(*a,i,j){a[i]^=a[j]^(a[j]=a[i]);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVPbbqMwFHzvVxwhpQLqaBNo2qQ0uw@r/QpCK0RMy6UkAqSNiPj1ZY8vgONQqQ9FwjaeOZcZm2ge5WHx1nWxaYckIal1Dv0keNmGfhq8mGzcsg3La7ukqOEjTArTgvMN4MM2alrVr0s/gC2c1wQ2BB4I3BN4JLBcEFjx1br1RrIjyILjDhQe5eCoct2Bu@Sgy8cN5z7wNaa@6CUXEVXS0ENsiu6sH/LTlt8EVNzRcEfDXQ13rbGmzYtWoqjITqRMObtag6@JIC@EJh1NBbri4lYKSk9HGtV035vN3FXdXutmDwGj4S4nfGL4wL8wfdOb7kybbg9xImpskygdKGt3QtPloY0pRuOVPaLTnAmacoZj5QnecJbRe1jaONIoo6Vox9id/ji70@Y3viuDgPrtGjIuPpRgMi1JsacnDFt4cvmsN3Bd3vLg7o6z@1@qdybHTOI6czjwVBQvnYSrKRgSieJVm4LTHk6v4GOJhNg0fMPSKjYY9BHm@SEy7@1cQQcDMiE@Q@E505WpmtjT@BnztcbJuwD6qrNqtkefs1/M7CcDRxai1GqvGg0IzPbshflP8DEiIZCq3ZnN1R5r9hhWFfay1FRS3Bvus27O15XK7Hy6vZXCMfO3KodZtSuQ2d9ZVk0NiUtKzUZutDdt9y@K8/Ct6uZ//wM)

*Port of [Unmitigated](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/99986/unmitigated)'s [C++ answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236318/9481)*

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <s>39</s> 33 bytes

```
Prompt L,A,B
ʟL(A→X
ʟL(B→ʟL(A
X→ʟL(B
ʟL
```

-6 bytes thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush).

Input indices are 1-based. Output is stored in `Ans` and is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/Errless/), 6 bytes

```
0m:r.M
```

A [macro](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/reference.md#-procedures-amp-macros).

### Explanation

```
0 { Push a 0 to the stack to identify the macro } 
m { Start macro definition }
: { (L a b) -> (L (a b)) }
r { Rotate }
. { Halt (Return) }
M { End macro definition }
```

You can test it with the following program:

```
0m
 :r.
M

{ Test cases: }

1,2x3x4x5x6x7x8x9xax 3 7
0" # a? { Outputs "(1 2 3 8 5 6 7 4 9 10)" and a newline }

3,8x1x4xaxaxaxax 0 5
0" # a? { Outputs "(10 8 1 4 10 3 10 10)" and a newline }

5,1x4x2x3x 0 4
0" # a? { Outputs "(3 1 4 2 5)" and a newline }

5,6x 0 1
0" # a? { Outputs "(6 5)" and a newline }

2,2x2x 0 1
0" # a? { Outputs "(2 2 2)" and a newline }
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1VvpdtvGFf7Pp5jItQlIJEVK3kKbTh1v1Yltubba04ZieIbAkIQNAshgaJFynJ99gD5iX8S9dxZgsJCSHatJ5WNKGMzc@9117ixM1mIeR4d3E/7pGnnKhDdnPpnyeEHmQiRpf39/FohOyjtzsf8rX9JonOwzzkOWpmPOpum@4IztL2gQ7QeCLfYnwSyIxHgZBV7ss/1EkTdDOsmaUEEOu@TYE/GEcXLQPeg1gkUSc0EonyWUp8w8p@vU/CmCBWs0vJCmKQmipN8g8OOzKRmPgygQ47GTsnDqqnb8wceOTwUlA9JsNrL@MybCIGLl7pyJJY@sUXvIvZMKP4g6nFFfDnKH/XZvVCAmCbVIGpyzQbtnUQymspHcJ93@xeQdN4cCiLOOwz4SGd0ryJO/xZf9UVkKXiWPHdshixzuugX8QVkTEZsBi6c0BDtUIKHAvRzq2TwIGeGdIE0T6oF@cjLbhoFq4BXYpd3sa34nfMnuXcAnigXhQzBAzo/QyM/afHA9UcWwV0/TVqikgEozbQXJubK6aRJ8XWKhtA5uD9pF4RAoisVAh6St2rMRbOWxRJC/03DJnnAe81piQ/Ay8HPgDp/gHA00V5jEiRO2SJB7GnAL0iBKBY1AH/AuDFLhnhqSqB7HCciDAenKhwD8Ed0gdF0Sc@Lgs3rjtAOX3B@Yt9XYCDvIPlCSWDAVMsbe/Y7QhsGoFlYKNkdULbL6H6JCOGC5lQVJ4ZmGVAjZPQODvlIDKEsZw1BLBgSH6s8p4GDgFyS0FNFhK6DsO4YFcwuG4gqAFydrm3sd57Jyh3IQcy2@BWWHirQfj5eOSSRS2LGzqlKbQmON3CvNXcXMEMauFcM1MlwVGE7HGUe/wrFF1hZT2iITjKEqo5bduNaNdoai0siT@ugETuctcqYg4l@I8jxIFP88V7AQKW2jocU8t8TMBm5mDmzOrYHrUY2akXZZbWoCfclA7knI@sadzij3QU0fMirNc8jMzR@brbzlA7Z8tFscbHHtlgW2vNAtH@XnhHrvquTX2PGf9tCP2PLBbnGxxbFbXmDLIiMvnSB9FyRjL14sGKTZhMezFkkEbxmp0gHOLMbhIw9g9NC65rXO0T353ptTDDOkMgQiSqkRKEumYU8@poIHEc5Y2FnNpHp2gn65vWA4TjxmlGm6rtIFcsidrZatxWtPM7OcUw0ZSKsUfESihQG9oidl/T/W9W9jf9tVHICxB9jd6xnalkZjaV3r0NY6koNOA1k@tAgkpMHLODL636jfMfij9w4zHHYZ1Shay80wI4MDA82@fBhkztzRcDSJkmUUh4p9eldiHUerAScMo/kcxLA7UnWLfAXRW5agaKFt1tbAW2SMhVNtJLiVATnuceWdF0cAfMkqPqKgd2iS4CSDgNyihzmoubynS76xtZtPrmVhZVlmKQcqrZa0r4sSS0b9TWiwHinBKKMYYLxnyoYngH8BvUog9LaHgclwf5Q4MHguHwjtP1ogGBE2R8LHz4@EllrU/GEDwgj9fx0RYpkA08@uMXEYc8zglSptVrLWVOJIUYqU5JiatUBNbcpjQYUcFCcXl971FKsD4sQUrQAW9QHEcUHQ20BBLHA9ly2V4gQDIKvoA5SW02jGnF7LkLPAQD2nCMBnq0AlGOUmNyse2YyrnkaptTuSdNwaLc04nTgp0LbUZNrHTtYkQ8Y4vlmSIlY1AJcBcoSLQ7T@l8pZ@ugrMhj7uFxG18FkJLUIJdsySvvEDzzQaPsBdtAF6jIq5B3ZeO0aeXPy8NEP5PjVk9cPT46OX75pGDvJAZAk@lAvXiOP4sgD60fwP18XSEMAdBUUWftkQ7vMZUXrU218tSwsvZyYl8XIKuSMIXSiIztaU9YvdpmQPULdslgrKdZD2eVCicLNEl3o/1XIYQ3kQvfQdKXuZjJhRaR7UqQ3LGH8Mmaqgqe14HH8kNozFaLQK2VqZRaD4xuJ41Wc5PorsS90/7Ps/hjTlmfjxgWDWmrLMFXD3UatMkQN3Zmk@wyiKBsTJ1sNnLPJXqhwxjYT0lVGzzJGas9Xdr@Yp01a/6olH0ryz1k0E/PC/lnJH3BLxNZUZbfsZJ3ozbLiyHavhutziyuJpyWhKpxt6xTocEnntZw7ijrJ9nFy3Wywrpl58o5Wrixwe21xq7PDVp6azTZbtCR9rDYaG2I7JzyqGf8nFaJnNPniLFoIPwzZidmMhmz@PBAQ/GHaKLKGSbHZ7R0c3rx1@87db@nEg/lESbJcTBhP64XBPVcY3SK923W6Pm2qmQEqIOoJm4pZF97bXAcXGMW67pczUx2rN0ptJ6@PXj5rFCrV1FSqNetovW6A0Rv4DpGxp@okD5WUDnu4S20lZz25A71Mxw/5WswXVAReo4p0T00rvv8b7asRyt25kC4mPsXaBWJ@tbd2cWakdXpqKz0tJwJNcmUQ2lsgjHWEzOx4LxNcZgT7pL1yC@FYQ3NX0nyxDEWQhOsrE2t3i1j7apIK3gf@lxdAcrVLp8wP3pf3WLOcrh1utb@/LrzUOfxHxmNEkQZxpHO5HtHdIqdmulm860rDsb8M498s3iL2LxTv@leWDnhulu701FgPun0N611CQrvXZ4rauowtbYFNZnoULxLKgzSOajLTQOrgyc9LGgbiyoKo3dt1VoPB2t1sjfu6skhTIuY0ulIk97cBeaDrNgapil89lgcWFmOx7wNxFqSM7JPn8QzK35Acy@odnCKtseGvKrken1wqs/56cWa9oaarl4@vLKne2JJUf5Hcj19fGfNftjD/STL/xxVy/2ldsfexmDNeY1ihYiIQImTk5KoQYUG32u11d3e3hcWJxPJ9MCOXczOkijRX7oXulthivrpaMQ@2S/kqk/LVpaU8qBMyT76R4HFInobxWY2FO5LfX2goyrWlPjcr9D6XvZ@a87VnsYgL1fXmolee1A27o7oKtsJmrZSg90w386nbnf8sRh8ko5OzuH1G12S2gU313OWy9Ieq8AUimdKycW8Xm1bgCW4xFLfhbau/BQyDRPRJ0hmPUybwatZ47MD87OAWYPuttYELbvHWbAjmUiXisgKMcgEyc1y5BHu/QQLj9q947DF/yVlKbpAX1ONx3cTlqC0h07e4hgP23kXLuBwXbnAOsx1yKxRHan/TU2u4S2l9IWHZjIvIFvRrAXPwyB3IKXDupdDtqM0MeMoUty81nLPc4BayEEXoBUxT@06FqkJ/YGtdfHoGJGSqnNCicouteILgVU8Q5IEPbt0NLSMYWpg0bFL51hFKrK4E4abkorRFNbRUlm7aq6tuaKbmbCGnu21ftrJ3cyFLjMtu6YZdIu89FRlhP9y/B30luGmhoS7UzQm944TGcsHiCxlFJFb7uCSOoDY1u1km7I6Oa6LsOx1lMFdl3K@V5rEE3zrenOsrRKv8xKS76vW68KPvDzVPu0116tpslma9nDo5AWjTOIRJD4//qDcP2HuWKsR0wSDX07ClNTNh2GdKU6i3rcNTiajZ7LyNg@jSyPLDrbo9PTcDbkE9IsECfBWnGOYDwiBVHzAltQCbR5dAW6JBmAxkAfI@LvlhzWTR8cyOFxH0Hcj68xLyKgnjCBLDZCksEu8Z7hVJxQiwo8fwvHmx9OYWNaWODqDb9eJl6O/mKEkagwZTvLobT4H0dKrWKQLvnCo2KEhsUUuFHwMEHszmAmQCJeFlswSaYi6NgvmL0wWqJ1Vwj2DKiJoCdRG9wz4WOTadIndUEvwGfQipdyQEEsJMTiHWAPuUrOMlKBIwixg8mbGQTDljRXC5YEAHBnC8KvpN1Y@v5X6MO5QN6xz5PUaicuZUHoQ5qbst8JW/OE2yR5rEuBiQKW77ufjabZZcUvazvaroVAXIf5WQj1DTeW6HgIeYbOGKvpBcdKhfclMSzNcxF65rN5V/znkX1PVl/DW7wKmrmgOL1SP7nkJlP1eTcXq1C4GjEp20tnxZ9S@nGkgYo3KGMonyRZDW7dM@VjtCbLKc/a7uZY4zppAfB/q6OeP8gusC@qgZJJ9GkGT17MvVLX05EwV4agNKUx1aeA4Ds2Aq@fQLF7Oxxb49b27Zg@w8P3keI18Hv41QOn7GCbBwBI23aOKI2SfRWZOP@lb3efIbBOq6TnYRJ7u9M7LON9P8vXwakA8flYqOXj49loUfYoHOkoWyizbk7rhFdnfH474kkI9ymqcCggPqHf2h5/ZyB1nrcZZwKb46o1BlXHZu1/zPv/7dLGYHXQtAEV2sBlRZLWsBoKap2wVA1lNBKOHSKpFS9uUXOjppyFjidLq98tAvRC9Njt9F0QhhEpvEKTPXsKo2vCa/b4Jime@edB7y2RIT/Sv5xtx@0R071PfHVPdwdtrvd1pkp93WfOBhzsJksJM9q7Gk5gdm4SCOBjupgHluLKC43HG3cfIVJylCxodFeHNIO84CRP56HJsYXE3NqClLJfQKvA8F@pUlgvpKD0FVN42aYDy6uKYofyHN1OgRHEArp1JFtdttSG/k0fHjJwQSHTw27cVGKs/UfXAaWBJA99PIep1dTYd@pfJVEQeHgkzGhv2bB6UCmQFdNrx50C@W/CoIQnmTvuaqmaJKwP1OBSGbaG@gXxD49ZM3f3t@UhC4kLSM28pP0KJ0b95sNj91F33eefHpAznBS7weTUF2vBbdax2sDlc3V7dWt1d3VndX367oihySO43uDngG/Y58IMdLAfNXSnacHjmAd3fJLXKb3CE3ybek13V35KqDkoid4dyNRA9bd1c9IEr1P1jx3Kon2AVqPaAEfxziRz29Wy2khkCB0s1aSoeSzAG5VT/@No7s1Y68XT/mABRzsHnUAfA6qBnXaYC29er3038B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:a[:b]+[a[c]]+a[b+1:c]+[a[b]]+a[c+1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Hcc7CoAwEAXAq6RU8grj34AnWbfYjYiCP8TG00dxujmfez72PE79EFfZdBQjUAQv5JUtCQVmK6TW@fBf/4fvHM9r2W8zJeSQo0CJCjUatOjgMoYpYJo0vg)

Comment: Sorry in a hurry ungolfed

Comment: [Looks like the simple mutating approach wins by 8 bytes, assuming you're allowed to mutate the input](https://tio.run/##Fcq9CoAgAEXhV3FMuENqZT/0JOKgptRiIjb09JbLgQ9Oest5R17r4QMJnYGFo6tRVsMop/cWNG7ZlydHYmrKVyz/qxg4BAaMmCAxYwHrNYgAkbR@)

Comment: @UnrelatedString I know but it's the first answer so I want to keep it ;) Life achievement

Comment: @UnrelatedString [Someone else also already posted that Python answer.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236304/52210)

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 46 bytes

```php
fn(&$a,$i,$j)=>[$a[$i],$a[$j]]=[$a[$j],$a[$i]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEETv@xU5LNLAHFqr1hKjHxIWSZHQFipBqr8ft/T0hjcDk8dcbo88ZuLkS3pXB47gCTxbfw8cA0@CDbOID3vArqU4Il6NN6HBES1OOOOCDlf0aGpxxFHLVjkou22dKl5h9MLwYB394uf5@i5ZrXXlDw)

changes the array in place, 0 indexing

My first shot was with `list`, but PHP has array destructuring since 7.1, so it ends up like the JS answer with lots of dollars (money money money!)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
İṘZ(n÷Ȧ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C4%B0%E1%B9%98Z%28n%C3%B7%C8%A6&inputs=%5B3%2C7%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%2C8%2C9%2C10%5D&header=&footer=)

This could almost certainly be a bit smaller, but I got smol brain and can't think of a good way to swap values.

Explanation:

```
İ        # Get the values at the indexes
 Ṙ       # Reverse the values
  Z      # Zip the values with the new indexes
   (n    # For each value/index pair:
     ÷   #  Split the value/index
      Ȧ  #  Put the value at that index
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 99 bytes

```
2`\d+
$*
1*(,1*);
$1,$&
(?<=(?=.*;(?<-2>\d+,)*(\d+))(1)*,(?(4)$)(?<-4>1)*(,1*)?;(\d+,)*)\d+
$1
.*;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxDsIwDER3f0dAdjhQnKYtKLQZ@QmGItGBhQHx/8EECcnS@d75/Frfj@etbviy1Lhc7ztyntQz1Esmp3Bb4nKeuEwHn23bx9muIJ5NRFjFgwsncfJN02ygtUvm36G0r0rWp1o7jFkR0SGhx4ARR5yggQL63JlRCzT8x3jKfaNWMqfmhqbRSPwA) Link includes test cases. Takes input in the form `a,b;L`. Explanation:

```
2`\d+
$*
```

Convert the indices to unary.

```
1*(,1*);
$1,$&
```

Make a second copy of `b` so that we now have `b,a,b;L`.

```
(?<=(?=.*;(?<-2>\d+,)*(\d+))(1)*,(?(4)$)(?<-4>1)*(,1*)?;(\d+,)*)\d+
$1
```

Match an integer in `L`, with index `$#4` equalling either `a` or `b` (using a .NET balancing group), then match the other index in `$#2`, and match the integer at that index as the replacement for this integer (also using a .NET balancing group).

```
.*;
```

Delete `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <s>24</s> 21 bytes

1-based indices, input is a list and a tuple of indices to reverse

```
Reverse~SubsetMap~##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyi1LLWoOLUuuDSpOLXEN7GgTllZ7X9AUWZeiUNadLWhjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWOpY6hQa1OtbGOeW3sfwA)

-3 bytes thanks to att.

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7Pyi1LLWoOLUuuDSpOLXEN7GgTllZ7X9AUWZeiUNadLWhjpGOsY6JjqmOmY65joWOpY6hQa1OtbGOeW3sfwA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 42 bytes

*Updated TIO link to show positive indices only per challenge instructions (thanks, [Kevin](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen)!)*

```perl
sub a{($a,$b,$l)=@_;@$l[$a,$b]=@$l[$b,$a]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY5BDoIwEEX3nmKCXZQEiTVhA8FwAHfGFTSmSMEmtVYKQWM8O5YKK3d/5r95Gc1bGY2j6Utgb4xYgMoAST/NzkmGZO4WNHXRFox@xt5wOAjTxfGpExIeAzbXvq4l95PV7QXZvRUNpDBFMzCteWUnsg1DEjkAI6Eq/iQB/MLOt/2swBZD68lgZeyPDKBYnLbXrVAdeMdpIVQDlhEXbmaYAFPVchgXKnePUdjsIV8k1EvGLw)

Takes arguments as (first index, second index, 0-bound array). Mutates array in-place. Works with arrays containing any valid values, not just positive integers!

Comment: The input-list will only contain positive integers, so you might want to change your TIO-link. But since it does work when I replace the `qw(foo bar baz)` with `qw(1 2 3)`, I've already upvoted your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 33 bytes

```
func[l a b][swap at l a at l b l]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY7BCsIwDIbve4r/5klYq6vVwx7Ca8ih21oU6jbmxMevWauGQPj@L4QsfkhXP4C4CpcUXmNPEQ4d0/PtZrgVG@bRIXIK0@Jdf8N3C1RBihQ0DjiigcEJFmeomoVt0eIslLCq/80SmKKb7OTCljW/zGykC2mxujDTvNzHFfSY4pC/67Dbt8gYSsCcPg)

1-indexed

Answer (score 2):

## [Core Maude](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php/The_Maude_System), 158 bytes

```
mod S is pr ARRAY{Nat,Nat0}*(sort Array{Nat,Nat0}to A). var I J X Y : Nat . op
s : A Nat Nat -> A . eq s(A:A,I,J)= insert(I,A:A[J],insert(J,A:A[I],A:A)). endm
```

#### Example Session

```
             \||||||||||||||||||/
           --- Welcome to Maude ---
             /||||||||||||||||||\
         Maude 3.1 built: Oct 12 2020 20:12:31
         Copyright 1997-2020 SRI International
               Sat Oct 16 22:01:13 2021
Maude> mod S is pr ARRAY{Nat,Nat0}*(sort Array{Nat,Nat0}to A). var I J X Y : Nat . op
> s : A Nat Nat -> A . eq s(A:A,I,J)= insert(I,A:A[J],insert(J,A:A[I],A:A)). endm
Maude> red s(0 |-> 1 ; 1 |-> 2 ; 2 |-> 3 ; 3 |-> 4 ; 4 |-> 5 ; 5 |-> 6 ; 6 |-> 7 ;
>       7 |-> 8 ; 8 |-> 9 ; 9 |-> 10, 3, 7) .
result A: 0 |-> 1 ; 1 |-> 2 ; 2 |-> 3 ; 3 |-> 8 ; 4 |-> 5 ; 5 |-> 6 ; 6 |-> 7 ;
    7 |-> 4 ; 8 |-> 9 ; 9 |-> 10
Maude> red s(0 |-> 3 ; 1 |-> 8 ; 2 |-> 1 ; 3 |-> 4 ; 4 |-> 10 ; 5 |-> 10 ; 6 |-> 10 ;
>       7 |-> 10, 0, 5) .
result A: 0 |-> 10 ; 1 |-> 8 ; 2 |-> 1 ; 3 |-> 4 ; 4 |-> 10 ; 5 |-> 3 ; 6 |->
    10 ; 7 |-> 10
Maude> red s(0 |-> 5 ; 1 |-> 1 ; 2 |-> 4 ; 3 |-> 2 ; 4 |-> 3, 0, 4) .
result A: 0 |-> 3 ; 1 |-> 1 ; 2 |-> 4 ; 3 |-> 2 ; 4 |-> 5
Maude> red s(0 |-> 5 ; 1 |-> 6, 0, 1) .
result A: 0 |-> 6 ; 1 |-> 5
Maude> red s(0 |-> 2 ; 1 |-> 2 ; 2 |-> 2, 0, 1) .
result A: 0 |-> 2 ; 1 |-> 2 ; 2 |-> 2
```

#### Ungolfed

```
mod S is
    pr ARRAY{Nat,Nat0} * (sort Array{Nat,Nat0} to A).
    var I J X Y : Nat .
    op s : A Nat Nat -> A .
    eq s(A:A, I, J) = insert(I, A:A[J], insert(J, A:A[I], A:A)) .
endm
```

The answer is obtained by reducing the function `s` with the list, given as a Maude array (e.g., `0 |-> 1 ; 1 |-> 2` for `[1, 2]`), and the two indices, zero-indexed.

Maude does have lists (e.g., `0 1` for the same list `[1, 2]`), but this is one case where it's actually shorter to use arrays (which are generally very verbose) because we don't need to use an array literal syntax in the code, and because we need indexing. The FAQ says [it's allowed to accept input as either an array or a list](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/16670/45870).

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript 38 bytes

```
(l,a,b)=>(l[a]=[l[b],l[b]=l[a]][0])&&l
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
è¹Rǝ
```

Since no one posted an 05AB1E answer yet and it's been a couple of days, I'm gonna post my prepared 4-byter.

First input is a pair of indices \$[a,b]\$, second input is the list \$L\$.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IpDO4OOz/3/P9pYxzyWK9pQx0jHWMdEx1THTMdcx0LHUsfQIBYA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfWWCS9Ghlf8Przi0Luj43P86/6Ojo411zGN1og11jHSMdUx0THXMdMx1LHQsdQwNYmN1FKKjDXRMgfLGQDFDoLyhARzBpE2A0qZgSaARMEFDsKAZMtcIKG8UGxsLAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
è    # Index the first (implicit) input into the second (implicit) input-list
 ¹   # Push the first input-indices again
  R  # Reverse them
   ǝ # Insert the values at those reversed indices into the (implicit) second input-list
     # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), <s>19</s> 18 bytes

```
{@^a[@^i].=rotate}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2iEuMdohLjNWz7YovySxJLUWJOWQqGCrYKinZ2hgrZCWX6QQZ6pQrZCm4ZCoE60Sr2OpqxIfq2mtUJwIVln7HwA)

0-based indexing.  Modifies the list in-place.  Takes the indices as a two-element list.

*Edit*: `rotate` has the same effect as `reverse` and is one character shorter.  D'oh!

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 27 bytes

```
#(assoc % %2(% %3)%3(% %2))
```

The first argument `%` is a vector of numbers (not a list!) so that we don't need to use the function `nth`.

Edit: [TIO](https://tio.run/##FYpBCoMwFET3nmKgBH5gFpqoUTyKuBCbQItoMe350@9mHo83236@f1csRZ4xIeEha87nBgPjRMdb4286a21Vyed6Hd/9gCTMDR09W3bsGThwZFMv8Aj6nDTDqQzo0COgxQjNpfwB)

Edit 2: And actually you cannot `assoc` a list anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 14 bytes

```
ＩＥθ⎇№ηκ§θ⁻Σηκι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMM5sbhEwzexQKNQRyEktSgvsahSwzm/FCiToaOQramj4FjimZeSWgGS983MKy3WCC7N1cjQBEkCiUxNILD@/z86WsFYR8FCR8FQR8FEx9AAjmJ1FKINdBRMY2P/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes the 0-indexed indices as a 2-element array. Explanation:

```
  θ             Input array
 Ｅ              Map over elements
    №           Count of
      κ         Current index in
     η          Input indices
   ⎇            If found then
        θ       Input array
       §        Indexed by
           η    Input indices
          Σ     Take the sum
         ⁻      Minus
            κ   Current index
             ι  Else current element
Ｉ               Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <s>51</s> <s>46</s> 38 bytes

```cpp
#define f(a,i,j)a[i]^=a[j]^(a[j]=a[i])
```

*Saved 5 bytes thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210).*

*Saved 8 bytes thanks to [AZTECCO](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/84844).*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYzbCoMwEETf/YoFH0xgC7U3Wy/9EVEIMZaVGiVGEMRvT03beRiY3Tkjx/HwktKFpOV7blROw2SNEv0zIG2hF6QZXwPY5cJGtaQVtEwgYcdFSVVdiLKraua98AfufDf7En5BGFNWUMAa4wnPeMEr3jDBOz4wPm6/3j5ozP5M@D8Phnl2ST3OYbJNmsphtpDnsHiLIMqCzX0A)

Comment: [46 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY3NCoMwEITvPsVCDyZlC7V/tmr6IiFCiLVEqpEYQRCfPTW2exjYnW9mVd8f3kr5ne7UZ6xehTaDsy/ZPiPdOWil7gidI1hHjs5AzTwXZLX2EgOgN23oLLkWJZO8ESUJysKB5osP0XwrCKS0lgtgMCd4wjNe8Io3TPGOD0yOy4@ryUqtZkr/u7HhI0xZiFMYXJVlyowOigKmIDHEebT4Lw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>52</strike> 49 bytes

(longer than the [approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236304/107342) by @pxeger, but **doesn't** mutate in-place

```
lambda a,b,l:l[:a]+[l[b]]+l[a+1:b]+[l[a]]+l[b+1:]
```

[Try it Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWN03SbHMSc5NSEhUSdZJ0cqxyog2sEmO1o3Oik2JjtXOiE7UNrZLA_EQwPwnIj4XqVcmxzcwrKC3R0OQqKMrMK1FI04DydWB0jiZE7YJd0YY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjqWOoYGsVzGXOYQFQA)

**EDIT:** Thanks @Stephen Universe for saving me few bytes!

---

56 bytes by using `list.pop` and `list.insert`:

```python
def f(a,b,l):l.insert(b,l.pop(a)),l.insert(a,l.pop(b-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMGCpaUlaboWNy1SUtMU0jQSdZJ0cjStcvQy84pTi0o0gDy9gvwCjURNTR24YCJUMEnXUFMTql8txzYzr6C0REOTK00DytKB0TmaXAVFmXklCjkQ1Qt2RRvqGOkY65jomOqY6ZjrWOhY6hgaxHIZc5lDVAAA)

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer!

Comment: Thank you! have been following some of the excellent answers on recent questions.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to codegolf!

You could shave of 3 bytes by removing the `0` from `l[0:a]`. Python slices lists from position `0` onwards by default. Additionally, [as per our rules, you can submit your answer as an anonymous function,](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9032/104707) removing the `f=`. 

[Try it online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728oLIkIz_PaMHiNNuYpaUlaboWNw1zEnOTUhIVEnWSdHKscqKtEmO1o3Oik2JjtXOiE7UNrZLA_EQwPwnIj4VqVMmxzcwrKC3R0OQqKMrMK1FI04DydWB0jiZE7YJd0YY6RjrGOiY6pjpmOuY6FjqWOoYGsVzGXOYQFQA)

Anyways, hope that helps!

Comment: ah ok didnt know about the `f`. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Icon](https://github.com/gtownsend/icon), <s>43</s> 34 bytes

-9 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

```
procedure s(l,a,b)
l[a]:=:l[b]
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY/LCoMwEEX3fsXoKoFZmFitjfglIQsfWYhWJfZBKf12m8RSbIchzJx7GEjXTOO6zmZqdHs1GhYyYIU1DQZZKVGKQdYq0GO7U85VNxIagK0ZRAkS/OxKSoYcEzxgihkeMccTsljZPVe4sxKbMEtZ/G1lQfYjpV6x51yU/kWZg/wHcuvyDXuq3OMnfdPmAb0owxnaCZ5L2BcfeDfdRS8k7CVTCBFEtNgYoS//7zc)

1-indexed

Comment: Can Icon modify the input-list directly, so you possibly won't need the `return l`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Yes, of course, lists are passed by reference. I relied on the value returned by the function to print the result, which was stupid :). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 49 bytes

```python
lambda l,a,b:l[:a]+[l[b]]+l[a+1:b]+[l[a]]+l[b+1:]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZDLboMwEEXX5CvuBsUuowrzSoLEqp9BWdgiJEguRJgs@vXUGEFpY8mPmTlzLM3je7z3XTw1xeek5ZeqJTRJUrkuc1kFpS5VVQW6lIHIlYuli5WNq6npB8jhZgim18@x7Tu0HRhjpSBEhJiQEFJCRjgRzoQLQYSVq5w44Zc777hk5TgdPA9uWedCCVcX4X5bob1TJwz/UfEG/bWlKzT/vwiSWRDv8ulrT7agYkazVyJyfdEOWjOc5wdPGnMdRjTsbR4bR1FskyMcP6S5wjdgsvBrgrInR93W6PoRD9sLdrMv3/D3I3wsEtpsfPoB)

The very simple way.

Answer (score 1):

## x86-16 machine code, 7 bytes

```
00000000: 8a01 8600 8801 c3                        .......
```

Listing

```
8A 01   MOV  AL, BYTE PTR[BX][DI]       ; put 'b' value into AL 
86 00   XCHG AL, BYTE PTR[BX][SI]       ; swap 'b' value with 'a' position 
88 01   MOV  BYTE PTR[BX][DI], AL       ; put 'a' value into 'b' position 
C3      RET                             ; return to caller
```

Input \$L\$ at `[BX]`, indices \$a\$ in `SI`, \$b\$ in `DI`, `0`-based.

A test with our old friend DOS DEBUG:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
f(l,a,b)=[l[a],l[b]]=[l[b],l[a]];l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEER/ZekpgSk0aRsroj8S9pAKlcIioXioXx@TVIU9zLw3bAzb2j5iSosSBMz66sUHhviZueS55MB8kRRilLfaqb1R3NbnK8emlIbuQUQtoF1rkPfewKLHgBEOJ0w4w3QMGkATl0GfmcnedP/L3IBc1WOV@cUBxy90R7W12uztD7BOHw)

1-indexed

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/), 30 bytes

`->(l,a,b){l[a],l[b]=l[b],l[a]}`

Mutates the input in-place. Direct port of @pxeger's [approach](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236304/107342) including the link below:

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsGiNNulpSVpuhb7dO00EnWSdHI0q3OiE2N1cqKTYm1BhA6IWwtRdFMjxza1LDFHIT21pJgrLRpE6ZXkx2fqIFg5sVwFCjkQ9Qt2RhvrWOgY6pjoGBrAUSyXAZcpRAEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 49 bytes

```
l=[1...L.length]
f(L,a,b)=\{l=a:L[b],l=b:L[a],L\}
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/dudtdrjp3r)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4djda5zapt)

Surprisingly readable (if you know a bit of Desmos) even after I code golfed it.

#### Python Equivalent (switching to 0-based)

```python
def f(L,a,b):
    returnList = []
    for l in range(len(L)):
        if l == a:
            returnList.append(L[b])
        elif l == b:
            returnList.append(L[a])
        else:
            returnList.append(L[l])
    return returnList
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 75 bytes

```
proc S {L a b} {set x [lindex $L $a]
lset L $a [lindex $L $b]
lset L $b $x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9NCoMwEIXXzSkekgMYf9veoCB04dK4MNZFIbVSIwghZ08zFVsKA/Pe@5hhxvTa@@n17FHDVuigHOw8GKxo9H28DSt4Bd61TFNK8g@oH1Dgq/P60U2/TcwKJEiRIUeBEkecIGIXkpLZNFgRkIi/5RAjZzb/5GGQfEa@ICWYTUKabJrWH6bFzIguI/UzZMMr2dKNXEU7vC5mp029fUN3y1aOEXP@DQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [C++ (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 36 bytes

```cpp
#define f(a,i,j)std::swap(a[i],a[j])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##vZDNasMwEITP0VMs5BALphD5p0kd1y8SchCyUhQS2djKDxg/uys7TWh76K0WQrC77MynUVX18qFUPzdWHc@FzkzZuFrLU86erYtWrqxzZqyjkzQ24G0/L/TeWE37QMLgwBtXpGlzlVUgt2YHuT3seE/@tGw2zu4imdfISb5TKxAiQowEr1hhjTeIZbdhw8psEI2w4o@yrIPB@5aS5DSqqfLsKMvoNjwLWmy@XB79sdC2ON4lOsb@YqEItAYJUOwpnvc7zhLJZDgJhA/Gx@Oz@ckQT8jwy1pMZh36r4f/aN71nw)

Comment: You can remove the space at `)std` for -1.

Comment: To my understanding, you are still needed to add `#include<algorithm>` or `#include<utility>` or any other libraries includes one of them in your byte count.

Answer (score 1):

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 36 bytes

```
$$(NF-1)+=$$NF-($$NF=$$(NF-1)),NF-=2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fRUXDz03XUFPbVkUFyNAAkbYwQU0dIGVr9P@/oYKRgrGCiYKpgpmCuYKFgqWCoQGQa8FlDOQYAllALgIpmHGZgkVBmgwVTLlA2oBGcBkpgCCQBQA)

### Expected input

The input is a list of integers separated by spaces; the last two integers are the indexes of the values that must be swapped:

```
Input:
3 8 1 4 10 10 10 10 1 6
\_________________/ | |
 List of integers,  | L> Second index
starting index at 1 |
                    L> First index

Output:
10 8 1 4 10 3 10 10
|           |
\___________/
   Swapped
```

### How it works

```
$$(NF-1)                        We take the integer which index is the value of the second-to-last integer,
        +=                      and add:
          $$NF                  the integer which index is the last integer
              -($$NF            minus itself,
                    =$$(NF-1))  except that it is now the integer which index is the second-to-last integer.
,NF-=2                          And let's remove the last two integers.
                                Phew! It should print the modified input, at last.
```

It uses this swapping oneliner: `a+=b-(b=a)`.

For better understanding: `NF` is the variable for the number of fields, i.e, the number of integers in the input. `$n` is the `n`th integer in the input, so `$NF` is the last integer, and `$(NF-1)` the second-to-last integer. `$$NF` equals `$($NF)`, that is the integer which index is the last integer.

`NF-=2` reduces the number of fields by two, ignoring the two indexes.

Answer (score 1):

## [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html), <s>18</s> 10 bytes

*Edit: -8 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
{⌽⌾(⊸⊏)}
```

[Try it at BQN online REPL](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/try.html#code=U3dhcCDihpAge+KMveKMvijwnZWo4oq44oqPKfCdlal9IAoKYXJyYXkg4oaQIOKfqDEsMiwzLDQsNSw2LDcsOCw5LDEw4p+pCmFiIOKGkCDin6gzLDfin6kgCmFiIFN3YXAgYXJyYXkKCg==)

<s>Probably not the tersest code, but it works, which was no trivial accomplishment for my very limited [BQN](https://mlochbaum.github.io/BQN/index.html) ability</s>.  Now quite short...
<s>Will try to golf-down better as my abilities (gradually) improve</s>.  ...thanks to Razetime.

```
Swap ← {⌽⌾(⊸⊏)}          # define Swap function:
                            # list of 2 indices to swap on left = 
                            # array on right = .
                            
         ⌾                  # 'under' = apply function on LHS
                            # to elements specified by RHS  
          (⊸⊏)            #   RHS: elements of  at indices 
        ⌽                   #   LHS: reverse
```

Comment: `{⌽⌾(⊸⊏)}` reads as pick the elements, reverse the picked elements, and put them back in the same place in the array.

Comment: @Razetime - Ha ha.  Well, that's how it should have been done.  Thanks!

Comment: the idea of Under is to a) apply right function as a transformation, b) apply left function to transformed data, c) invert the transformation. With this understanding, you can do some very interesting things for golf.

Comment: @Razetime - That's a great explanation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 3 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍜⊏⇌
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=U3dhcCDihpAg4o2c4oqP4oeMCgpTd2FwIDFfMyBbMTAgMjAgMzAgNDAgNTBdClN3YXAgMF8xIFs1IDZdCg==)

0-indexed.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 75 bytes

```cs
List<int> f(List<int> L,int a,int b){var x=L[a];L[a]=L[b];L[b]=x;return L;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZO9TsMwEIDn@ClOnRLpiJrS0qJQlg4sYYEBqqqDa9xiKTjIdkqqKM8ezqW/LEyoln0@@3znzyefsFfCira0Sq/geWOd/IgnRZ5L4VShbfwgtTRKpOz0RMqYyLm18MrqnTZldZsp6@6UdvewDI96hjQB38pFVK@5gWqczfg89YK0hdcW83GVGulKoyFLm/azXORKwLpQb/BU6jCim8C3mgXH2HwMWn7BYaNOsIfX2McB3uAQR3iLSbdJt57BMuRkG0b7ZWEkF@@h56pAaeARTOjJRS7jF6OcDDt1t4EOVuQRnFkypcna2UVqGPsbDK4RRggJQp@QDv2UrYuDy7ANMKGUUeIoa@dA/UsB/eJILsPRo6T0/p@EWPzYfXnruNv//EeudGidodKbzYGblfV1EPga2sAP7TT08TfxtkhSitO03w)

Working only for int's. Thinking about evolving it to generics after.

Comment: [34 bytes](https://tio.run/##xZPfa8IwEMefm7/i8CmFW7H@mI5aYfiwl@5le9hEFGIWXaBLRxOdUvq3d9dORfeyp2FIjksu9@WTIyftjbSy2lht1vC8t059BJMsTZV0OjM2eFBG5VpG7PxGxJhMhbXwyoqDNyXvvskZJdq6kTZujEC2MWNYQVzxBAUu/XhcJDMxX8TJbDlf8NrG9YEflRUpf26WqZawzfQbPG0M90kZ6lEw7yQNIgajvuB0UITYwS72sI@3OMAh3mHYLqMm01txQbGBf9xmuRLynVMe7AgPhA8TemyWquAl107xVtEuoYU7yvAuIok2FG0dlErG/gaDLsIQIUToEdJpnrO1sX8dtj6GVDIqHFXtEqh3LaBfHOF1ODpUlM7/kxBLvQ5f3jrhjj//UWjDrcup6WZzEPna1n3gbUUOe/ihnfJafx80TRKRTll9Aw) (only works for ints).

Comment: In that case, I am in doubt if I should or not taking into the byte count the `Action` part or not.

Comment: No, you don't have to count them for lambda functions. Let me see if I can find the relevant meta-discussion for it.

Comment: Took a while to find, but [here is one of the many discussions](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11223/untyped-functions-in-static-languages). The top-voted answer allowing it without types has 17 upvotes, and the others against it are in the negative. (Small note: [recursive lambdas, or using multiple lambdas](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12680/multiple-functions-without-leading-trailing-mandatory-parts) isn't allowed, so those should still be in the full-written style in C#/Java.)

Comment: Anyway, if you prefer to keep your current style instead of the lambda, it could be: [55 bytes](https://tio.run/##xZNNb8IwDIbPza@wOKWSV1E@BlPHLhx26S7bYUMIpJAFFqlLpyYwUNXf3jnlQ7DLThNRYiV2/OqJFUt7I62s11abFbzsrFOf0TjPMiWdzo2NHpVRhZYJO7@RMCYzYS28sfKwm7Cy3uT6HZY81dbda@MeUiQLorGLsEynYjYfpdPFbM69HXlHmFT113qRaQlN@vPa8JBUwY@SBScxECMw6htOjjLGDnaxh328xQEO8Q7jdpU0mcGSC4oNwuMxL5SQH9yTbEEbECGM6Xl5pqLXQjvFW2W7ghZuKSO4iKTaULR1UKoY@xsMughDhBihR0inec7Wxv512PoYU8mocFS1S6DetYB@ccTX4ehQUTr/T0Isfh2@vHXCHX/@k9CGW1dQm01nIIqV9X0QbEQBO9jTTrjX30VNkySkU9U/). 