# Rotate N Values in a List

Tags: code-golf, array

Similar to [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/236301/swap-two-values-in-a-list).

Input a list and rotate N numbers in it given their indices. The following example uses 1-indexing, but feel free to use either.

In other words, take a list of indices and a list of numbers:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
[1,3,6]

Separate out the elements at those indices:

[  2   4 5   7]
 1   3     6

Rotate those left:

[  2   4 5   7]
 3   6     1

Insert them back in

[3 2 6 4 5 1 7] 

And there's your result!
```

### Testcases

```
[4, 1, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3] -> [1, 3, 4, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 3, 6] -> [3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 1, 7]
[5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 5] -> [5, 1, 7, 2, 6, 3, 4]
[3, 2, 6, 4], [1, 3] -> [6, 2, 3, 4]
```

### Rules

- You can assume the N indices are given in order and they're distinct.
- Default I/O rules apply, standard loopholes are banned. This is code-golf, so shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: Some more test cases would be needed, specially some in which the values don't equal the indices, and are not sorted. Also specify if the indices can be taken zero-based. They seem to be 1-based in your example. Is it possible that an index is repeated, or are they all distinct?

Comment: @wasif I think the values at 1-based indices 1,3,6 are written into positions 6,1,3 respectively. So, that sub-list is rotated to the left

Comment: @LuisMendo Distinct, I'm lazy at the moment to modify the challenge but you can refer to the linked challenge.

Comment: @null The challenge must be self-contained. Also, potential answerers do not know which features of the linked challenge would translate to this, and which would not

Comment: @LuisMendo I'll do it tomorrow maybe or maybe someone help me

Comment: I can help, but I cannot decide for you. Can indices be taken zero-based? (I suggest yes, let the answer choose)

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes, like the swap challenge.

Comment: This challenge is like, showing off that I'm back

Comment: That you are back and that you don’t care enough about your challenge to specify it properly? :-/

Comment: @LuisMendo exactly :(

Comment: @LuisMendo - Just joking. I will do so later but I'm programming with BF (not for this though) rn

Comment: May we assume that the contents of the lists are all non-negative integers? And do we have any lower bound on N? Can it be 0 or 1?

Answer (score 8):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 35 bytes

```r
function(a,i){a[i]=a[c(i,i)[-1]];a}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRJ1OzOjE6M9Y2MTpZIxPIi9Y1jI21Tqz9n6ZhaGWmZWigk6xhqGOsY6ap@R8A)

Comment: I'm not *completely* sure it always works, but can you save a byte by overloading the first set of indices into ```a``` instead, so that the replacements are recycled [like this](https://tio.run/##K/qfpmCj@z@tNC@5JDM/TyNRJ1OzOjE6WSMz2jAWyI61TYzOjLVOrP2fpmFoZaZlaKCTrGGoY6xjpqn5HwA)...?

Answer (score 6):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 11 bytes

```
(1|.{)`[`]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NQxr9Ko1E6ITYmv/a3KlJmfkK2gYKBgpmGoqpCkY6igY6SgY6yiY6CiY6iiY6SiYK/g56SlEG4MlzGASQHXmsf8B)

- `}` Amend...
- `]` The right argument...
- `[` At the indexes specified by the left argument...
- `(1|.{)` With the current values at those indexes `{` rotated once `1|.`

Answer (score 6):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 24 bytes

-1 byte thanks to @att.

```
RotateLeft~SubsetMap~##&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zg@z8ovySxJNUnNa2kLrg0qTi1xDexoE5ZWe1/QFFmXkl0WnS1oY6CkY6CsY6CiY6CqY6CmY6Cea2OAkgYKGZWGxv7HwA)

Comment: Infix for -1 byte

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
yy)w1YS(
```

Indices are 1-based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/v7JSs9wwMljj//9oQwMdBSMgNgZiEyA2BWIzIDY3iOWKNgSKA7mxAA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8L@yUrPcMDJY479LyP9oEx0FQx0FYx0Fo1iuaCDLCMhBsHQUgPKmOgpmOgrmEFGgkBmQBRUDa4YqBIoaQdQDWcZgYTOIMEhbLAA).

#### Explanation

Consider inputs `[10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]`, `[1, 3, 6]` as an example. As usual, the stack is shown with the most recent element below.

```
yy    % Take the two inputs implicitly. Duplicate them
      % STACK: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
      %        [1, 3, 6]
      %        [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
      %        [1, 3, 6]
)     % Reference indexing: takes entries in first input indexed by the second
      % STACK: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
      %        [1, 3, 6]
      %        [10, 30, 60]
w     % Swap
      % STACK: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
      %        [10, 30, 60]
      %        [1, 3, 6]
1YS   % Rotate 1 position to the right
      % STACK: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
      %        [10, 30, 60]
      %        [6, 1, 3]
(     % Assignment indexing: overwrites the first input with the values from
      % the second at the positions given by the third
      % STACK: [30, 20, 60, 40, 50, 10, 70]
```

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 48 bytes

Expects `(list)(indices)`, 0-indexed.

```javascript
a=>b=>a.map((v,i)=>b[j]^i?v:a[b[++j]||b[0]],j=0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDBbsIwDIbvfQofE2EKLayThtKd9hSWJzkd3VpBg2DqiXfvkjSF@ZT8/vzFSi@j3Jprd/ldD@7rOLVmElNbU0t@lotSI3ba36nnz@59fBOytFr1fL9b2jJjb7Z6OlAGQEB7hAJhh1AyAvlj6W8Mj/LpZhMbntkHbJ5LZMxeECqE1yTwWcXL3C5i1YIVAZsFaShmyRQE5Yw@BGlo0URsFjzVy8P/1g6bQxRUT33GWd6664c0P0qRIFjWYGpo3HBzp2N@ct@qVaKVjf84hN4Aayi0r@kP)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>             // a[] = main list
b =>             // b[] = list of indices (0-indexed)
a.map((v, i) =>  // for each value v at position i in a[]:
  b[j] ^ i ?     //   if b[j] is not equal to i or b[j] is undefined:
    v            //     leave v unchanged
  :              //   else:
    a[ b[++j] || //     increment j and use a[b[j]],
       b[0]      //     or a[b[0]] if it's undefined
    ],           //     NB: because the indices are given in order, '0'
                 //     may only appear at position 0 in b[] and cannot
                 //     trigger the b[0] failover
  j = 0          //   start with j = 0
)                // end of map()
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 58 bytes

```rust
|a:&mut[_],b:&[_]|for w in b.windows(2){a.swap(w[0],w[1])}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCoJAEIbvPcWfB1lhErUsMKwHEQlNhQVdxV3Zg/rsplvSZeYw3/dNP0i1VAJNxgVzMKIuFap4mbLIbgaVvFLKI3tdU9X20OACuau5KFotWeCMmSt11jGdeCnpxE@deQHuB5gOF92gECPxCQHhTLgQQsKVcEt3aP2CmsuNM/xfLvi7lJvuUUChESpm7zzB/iHOdul6LlQtjswao@dM2CZOD7Mt@qZpj5IprN68fAA)

0-based indexing. Changes the input array in-place.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

```python
def f(L,I):
 r=L[I[0]]
 for i in I[::-1]:r,L[i]=L[i],r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw7CoAwEAX7nGJLhSf4FwI5QCA3WLbTYJooi42nj4rNwBQz533tRx5KWbdIsQrwtTWkLrDnVsRQPJQSpUyerW06sYrASdwHaHkDxx16DBgxYcYi4Pb1Scy/M6emfFWhLg8)

0-based, in-place. Works for length 1 but not length 0 index list.

Answer (score 3):

## [Raku](http://raku.org/), 18 bytes

```
{@^a[@^i].=rotate}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/2iEuMdohLjNWz7YovySxJLUWJOWQqGCrYKinZ26tkKbhkKijEG2go2Cko2Aaq2mtUJwIUvAfAA)

0-based indexing.  Changes the input array in-place.

This is the same answer as my answer to the "swap two values in a list" question.

Answer (score 3):

## APL+WIN, 19 bytes

Prompts for inices then vector

```
n[i]←(n←⎕)[1⌽i←⎕]⋄n
```

[Try it online!Thanks to Dyalog Classic](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v@ob6qvz6O2CcZcQJanP5BlyPWooz3tf150ZiyQp5EHJIBSmtGGj3r2ZkI4sY@6W/L@A5Vx/U/jMlQwVjADkkZA2kTBVMFMwZyLiwsA)

Comment: `1⌽@⎕⊢⎕` using Dyalog APL's @

Comment: @rak1507 Thanks but my ancient APL+WIN interpreter does not have the same functionality as a modern version of Dyalog. Why not submit your answer to show what a modern interpreter can do.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 8 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
{1⌽@⍺⊢⍵}
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=qzZ81LPX4VHvrkddix71bq0FAA&f=M1QwUjBWSFMwUTAE0kZcINIMyDcEi5somAJ55lxGYFYahAeTA6tNA@kCipoAAA&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

A dfn submission which takes indices on the left, array on the right.

Comment: 1@⌽⎕⊢⎕ using a full program

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 16 bytes

```
ＩＥθ⎇№ηκ§θ§η⊕⌕ηκι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NUy9CsIwEN59ihsTOMG/ujhJQOggOLiVDEcSaLC92BhFnz5eBb/p@3c9ZZdoqPVMd5PGkdirCeEaMlP@KJOeXFSPcNMIx9KyD@85/1NJWnY5jIFL8OoUZf5rCxCi1ofFJUe5MPQoahJda9etENYIG4Qtwg6hQdhbhNkWr7G2Ll/DFw) Link is to verbose version of code. 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
  θ                 Data array
 Ｅ                  Map over values
    №               Count of
      κ             Current index
     η              In index array
   ⎇                If index present then
        θ           Data array
       §            Indexed by
          η         Index array
         §          Indexed by
            ⌕       Index of
              κ     Current index
             η      In index array
           ⊕        Incremented
                ι    Otherwise original value
Ｉ                   Cast to string
                    Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Core Maude](http://maude.cs.illinois.edu/w/index.php/The_Maude_System), <del>242</del> 219 bytes

```
mod R is pr LIST{Nat}. ops r x : Nat Nat ~> Nat . var A B I J : Nat . var R X
Y :[Nat]. ceq r(X A Y,I R)= X x(A I Y,R)if size(X)= I . ceq x(A I X B Y,J R)=
B X x(A J Y,R)if size(X)+ s I = J . eq x(A I X,nil)= A X . endm
```

The result is obtained by reducing the `r` function with the two lists (given as Maude lists) with zero-indexing. It is assumed the indices are distinct and ordered.

This solution only works for \$N > 0\$. It wouldn't be difficult to handle \$N = 0\$, but it would be expensive byte-wise. (It would require an extra equation.)

#### Example Session

```
             \||||||||||||||||||/
           --- Welcome to Maude ---
             /||||||||||||||||||\
         Maude 3.1 built: Oct 12 2020 20:12:31
         Copyright 1997-2020 SRI International
           Sat Nov  6 01:42:43 2021
Maude> mod R is pr LIST{Nat}. ops r x : Nat Nat ~> Nat . var A B I J : Nat . var R X
> Y :[Nat]. ceq r(X A Y,I R)= X x(A I Y,R)if size(X)= I . ceq x(A I X B Y,J R)=
> B X x(A J Y,R)if size(X)+ s I = J . eq x(A I X,nil)= A X . endm
Maude> red r(1 2 3 4 5 6 7, 0 2 5) .
result NeList{Nat}: 3 2 6 4 5 1 7
Maude> red r(1 2 3 4 5 6 7, 2) .
result NeList{Nat}: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

#### Ungolfed

```
mod R is
    pr LIST{Nat} .
    ops r x : Nat Nat ~> Nat .
    var A B I J : Nat .
    var R X Y : [Nat] .
    ceq r(X A Y, I R) = X x(A I Y, R) if size(X) = I .
    ceq x(A I X B Y, J R) = B X x(A J Y, R) if size(X) + s I = J .
    eq x(A I X, nil) = A X .
endm
```

---

Saved 23 bytes by prepending `A` and `I` to the first list rather than passing as a separate parameter. This requires a new function `x`, but `x` can be declared in the same `ops` declaration as `r`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
İǓZ(n÷Ȧ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C4%B0%C7%93Z%28n%C3%B7%C8%A6&inputs=%5B0%2C2%2C5%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%5D&header=&footer=)

```
İ       # Get the elements at those indices
 Ǔ      # Rotate
  Z     # Zip with the indices
   (n   # Foreach
     ÷Ȧ # Assign that index to that value
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
èÀ¹ǝ
```

First input-list are the 0-based indices, second the full list.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IrDDYd2Hp/7/3@0gY6RjmksV7QhkDbWMdEx1THTMY8FAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WmVBsr6SQmJeioGQPZDxqmwRkVCa4FB1a@f/wisMNh9Ydn/tf5390dLSBjqGOUaxOtAmQNgayYnUUQIJGOqZAQaAUUNBEx1THTMccIgVSZQKUAgvpQBXAdQElgIYApYBCsQA).

A minor alternative could be `è¹Áǝ`: [try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8IpDOw83Hp/7/3@0gY6RjmksV7QhkDbWMdEx1THTMY8FAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
è     # Get the values from the second (implicit) input-list at the indices of the first
      # (implicit) input-list
 À    # Rotate those values once towards the left
  ¹ǝ  # Insert them back into the second (implicit) input-list at the indices of the
      # first input-list
      # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)

è     # Same as above: get the values at the indices
 ¹    # Push the first input-list of indices again
  Á   # Rotate the indices-list once towards the right
   ǝ  # Insert the values at those indices back into the second (implicit) input-list
      # (after which the list is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + numpy, <strike>34</strike>, 30 bytes (@Neil)

```python
def f(L,I):L[I]=L[I[1:]+I[:1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hYyxCsMgFEV3v8JR20fRpGlByAcI/oG8QWjSZsiLWDv49daSoUOHLhfu5ZwbS35s1Nd6m2Y@CwdWGuctji28Nni03mjEuqxxS5nTa42FhyenyFiDR4qnkFIowmvooIczDHCBK0rwqg0Dsv2UxbRQFk5@rUD3SWilVGMPe1Pw6dDJf9rQnF@mvgE)

[Old version](https://tio.run/##hYxBCoMwFET3OUWWSRlKorWFgAcQcoPwF4Fq68L4Se3C06dWl110NfNg3vC6POdUl3LvBzkoj047HzpqfQinLlhH2MJZIirjxHNeZHpPvMr4komF2IR2iqwSn2POcYUKFhVqXNDgihshmI0b0loc94LzmBbl9e7uXkyPXlljjMbRDb6E6p/TaAT62ZQP)

0-based, in-place. Data L must be a numpy array, index I <strike>can be many things: range, array, list, but not tuple</strike> must be a list. I can be empty.

[The fine print](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10085/107561)

Comment: ... although you could save 4 bytes by only allowing a list for `I`...

Comment: Good point. After all, golf is not the place for defensive progamming ;-) WIll edit.@Neil

Answer (score 1):

## [ErrLess](https://sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/Errless/), 44 bytes

```
0ml0$:Y@;2/<1-[{@;$@1+3G$-:1G$r$;$1+$:y}!r.M
```

A [macro](https://man.sr.ht/%7Eruan_p/errless_docs/reference.md#-procedures-amp-macros).

### Explanation

```
0m {...} M { Macro identified by 0, takes two stacks as input: (list indices) }

l0$:Y@;2/<1-[{@;$@1+3G$-:1G$r$;$1+$:y}! { Reverse indices list }
l0$:                                    { Add (0 #-of-indices) to the top of the stack: (list indices (i N)) }
    Y {...} 1-[{ {...} y}               { While }
     @;2/<                              { i < N // 2 }
              @;$@1+                    { (list indices (i N) N i i+1) }
                    3G$-:               { (list indices (i N) (i N-i-1) }
                         1G$            { (list (i N) indices (i N-i-1) }
                            r           { Swap the i-th and i-th from last elements of indices: (list (i N) indices) }
                             $          { Swap: (list indices (i N)) }
                              ;         { (list indices i N) }
                               $1+$     { (list indices i+1 N) }
                                   :    { (list indices (i+1 N) }
                                      ! { Pop: (list indices) }

r. { Rotate & halt (return) }
```

The biggest difficulty was reversing the indices list, as ErrLess rotates to the right, not to the left. If we had to rotate right the macro would be very easy: `0mr.M`. Exactly the same as in [this answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236560/91340), in fact.

You can test it with the following program:

```
0ml0$:Y@;2/<1-[{@;$@1+3G$-:1G$r$;$1+$:y}!r.M

{ Uses 0-based indexing. Appended "1-" to the end of the list of indices to convert to 0-based indexing }

1,2x3x4x5x6x7x 1,3x6x 1- 0"# a? { -> (3 2 6 4 5 1 7) }

4,1x3x2x 1,2x3x 1- 0"# a? { -> (1 3 4 2) }

1,2x3x4x5x6x7x 1,3x6x 1- 0"# a? { -> (3 2 6 4 5 1 7) }

5,6x7x1x2x3x4x 2,4x5x 1- 0"# a? { -> (5 1 7 2 6 3 4) }

3,2x6x4x 1,3x 1- 0"# a? { -> (6 2 3 4) }

.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vvrdts2Ev6vp0BspyJtSRbtJO0qUZo0t/VpEmcTd8@2slaHIiGJCUWyABRLdtOf@wD7iPsi2RkAJMGLZOfibdfnRBFBYOabKwYXJSsxi6PD7xL2cZs8pcKbUZ9MWDwnMyES3tvfnwaiw1lnJvZ/Zws3GiX7lLGQcj5idML3BaN0f@4G0X4g6Hx/HEyDSIwWUeDFPt1PFPl0SCdZkQfkDnkZv6fzMWXkoHvgNBrBPImZIC6bJi7jNH3mK55@FcGcNhpe6HJOgijpNQj8@XRCRqMgCsRoZHEaTmzVjn/42PFd4ZI@aTYbWf8pFWEQ0XJ3RsWCRcaoPeTe4cIPog6jri8H2YNe2xkWiElCLcKDc9pvOwbFYCIbyT3S7V1O3rJzKIA46zjoIZHh3YI8@Vt82RuWpWBV8tixHdLIYrZdwB@UNRHRKbB46oZghwokFNjJoZ7NgpAS1gk4T1wP9JOT2TRMsFWxI@gK@oKh2s2eBnDCFvTuWgo58ygWhA3AKjkI4kZ@1uaDP4oyMAVubz1tU9uSEmo0bavIyJRbFJqVJSAUQOMoH@JEySjolbRVezaCLj2aCGL93Q0X9AljMWuRo8inS/m9rFVFegB@CJEA7OET3KeBBg2TOLHCFglyXwTeAQ8iLtwIlAPvwoAL@zQlibqyrIDc75OufAjAY9FRQtsmMSMWPqs3Vjuwyb1@@rYaPWEH2QdKLgOmQkbpuz8Q2iAY1sLiYHxE1SLL/yEqhAOWWxqQFJ5J6Aohu2dg0HNqAGVJZRBqyYDgQH2dAA4KfkFCQxEdugTKvpWyoHbBUEwB8OJkZXKv41xW7kAOorbBt6DsUJH249HCSlONFHZkLavUJtBYI/dSc1cRNICxK8VwhQyXBYaTUcbRr3BskZXB1G2RMcZQlVHLbFzpRjO9u9LI4/roBE7nLXKmIOI3RHkeJIp/nixoiJQ20dBinhtiZgPXMwc258bA1bBGzUi7rDY1xb6kIPc4pL3Unc5c5oOaLjIqzXNI1c1fmq285QJbPpgtFrbYZsscW17olg/yc@x676rkV9jxZ3PoB2y5MFtsbLHMlhfYMs/ISyfg74Jk5MXzOYWkm7B42iKJgASrpeJ9nGpSh488gOGgddPXOmM78r03czHMkMoAiCilRqAsmYY9@cgFCyKcwrCzmmv1VAX9cnvBcJyB0lFp002VLpBD7my1bA1ee5qZ4ZxqSF9apeAjEi0McIqelPX/UNe/jf1NV7EAxh5gt29maFsajaF1rUNT60gOOvVlgdEikJD6L@Mo1f9a/Y7AH713mOGwy7BG0VpuihkZHBho9uRDP3PmjoajSZQsozhU7ONci3UsrQacMFLN5yAG3aEqYuQriN6yBJXqaa21NfAWGWElVRsJdmVAjntUeefFEQBf0IqPKOgdN0lwkkFAdtHDLNRc3tMmN0zt5pNrWVhZnxnKgVKrJe1ro8SSUW8dGqxHSjDKKPoY75my4QngX0KvEgjO5jBIM9yfJQ5SPFcPhPafLRBSEdZHwodPj4SWWvb8aQMiFfr/OiLEIgGmn1xj4jBqpYOXqrRZylpTiSNFKVKSY2rWAjW1KYuFK@SgOLm89K6nWB0QJ2nRCmBRH0AcFwTOGgpijuu5bKkUJxgAWUUfoLTMjabUclopOQMM1HOKAHy2ClSCYW7ydMUjm3HV0yi1doeSjl2jpSlzxxYH2oaa0vaRlTXJkEkdP12SIlY1AJcBcoSNQ7T@F8pZeugrMhh7uHhG18FkJLUIJdsi4j3iBx5otH0fO@gCdREV8o5s3N4mb04ePvqRHL968vrhydHxyzeN1E5yACSJHtSL2@RRHHlg/Qj@5esCaQiAroIiax@vaZe5rGh9VxtfLQtLL8fpy2JkFXLGADq5QzNaOe0Vu4zJHnHtslhLKdZD2eVSicL1El3q/1XIYQ3kQvcw7era68mEFZHuSpHe0ISyq5ipCt6tBY/jB645UyEKvVJ2jcyS4rghcbyKk1x/JfaF7g9k98eYtjwTNy4Y1FJbhqkabjdqlSFq6E4l3WcQRdmYONlo4JxN9kKFM7alIV1l9CxjpHaFZffLeZqk9X@15ENJ/jmNpmJW2B8s@QNuiZiaquydnawStXNWGtl2arg@N7iSeFISqsLZtE6BDpN0Xsu5o6iTbB8n180a66YzT97RyJUFbq8NbnV22MhTs9lki5akj9VGY01s54SHNeN3VIieuclnZ9FC@GHIjtPtasjmzwMBwR/yRpE1TIrNrnNweOv2nW@/@4s79mA@UZIs8IiB1wuDO7AwukWcO3W6Pm2qmQEqINcTJpV0XXh3fR1cYBTrul/OTHWs3ii1nbw@evmsUahUeVqp1qyj9boBRq/hO0DGnqqTPFQSHzi4TW0kZz25A71Mxw/ZSszmrgi8RhXpnppWfP8L7asRyt250J2PfRdrF4j55d7KxpnRrdNTW@lpMRZokmuD0N4AYaQjZGrGe5ngIiPYI@2lXQjHGpq7kuaLRSiCJFxdm1i7G8TaV5NU8D7wP78Akqtdd0L94H15jzXL6drhlvv7q8JLncN/oSxGFDyII53L9YjuBjk10/Xi3VQajv1FGH@xePPYv1S8m19ZOuC5XrrT09R60O1rWO8KEpq9PlHU1lVsaQqcZqZH8TxxWcDjqCYz9aUOnvy6cMNAXFsQtZ1da9nvr@z11rinKwvOiZi50bUiubcJyH1dt1FIVez6sdw3sKQW@yEQZwGnZJ88j6dQ/obkWFbv4BS8xoa/q@R6fHKlzPr75Zn1GzVdvXx8bUn1mw1J9TfJ/fj1tTH/bQPzf0rm/7hG7v9cVex9LGaU1RhWqJgIhAgpObkuRFjQLXed7u7uprA4kVh@CKbkam6GVJHm0r7U3RJTzFfXK@bBZilfZVK@urKUB3VC5sk3EiwOydMwPquxcEfy@6sbinJtqc/NCr3PZe@n6fnas1jEhep6fdErT@oG3WFdBVths1JK0Hum6/nU7c5/EqMLyejkLG6fuSsyXcOmeu5yVfoDVfgCkUxp2bi383Ur8AS3GIrb8KbV3wKGfiJ6JOmMRpwKvLw1GlkwP1u4Bdh@a2zgglu8TTcEc6kScVUBhrkAmTmuXYK9L5AgdftXLPaov2CUk2/IC9djcd3EZaktobRvcQ0H7L3LlnE5LtzgHGQ75EYoDtX@pqfWcFfS@lzCMhkXkc3drwXMwiN3IKfA2VdCt6U2M@ApU9y@1HDOco1byEIUoRcwTcw7FaoK/ZGudPHppSAhU@WE5pV7bsUTBK96giAPfHDrblC67zXXV9ZMUvnWEUqsrgThpuS8tEU1MFTG1@3VVTc0eXq2kNPdtC9b2bu5lCXGZbd01y@R956KjLAf7t@DvhLctNBQ5@rmhN5xQmPZYPG5jCISq31cEkdQm6a7WWnYHR3XRNn3Ospgrsq4b5fmsQTfWt6M6StEy/zEpLt0nC786ftDzdNuU526NpulWS@nTk4A2iQOYdLD4z/XmwX0PeUKsTunkOvdsKU1M6bYZ@JyqLeNw1OJqNnsvI2D6MrI8sOtuj09OwNuQD0iwRx8FacY6gPCgKsPmJJagM1zF0BbokGYFGQB8j4u@WHNZNDx0h0vItx3IOuvC8irJIwjSAzjhTBIvKe4VyQVI8COHsXz5vnCmxnUlDo6gG7Xixehv5ujJDwGDXK83BtPgPRkotYpAm@lKjYoSGxQ48KPAQILpjMBMoGS8LJZAk0xk0bB/MXcOaqHK7hHMGVETYG6iN5hH4McnUyQOyoJ/gd9CKl3JAQSwkzuQqwB9glZxQtQJGAWMXgypSGZMEqL4HLBgA4MYHhf9EbVj7dzP8YdyoZxjvweI1E5M5cHYRa3NwW@8herSfZIk6QuBmSK2342vrabJZeU/UyvKjpVAfLfJOQj1HSe2yHgISZbuKIvJBcd6lfclATzddIr2bWbyr/mvAvq@jz@ml1g1VXNgcHqkXlPobKfq8lYTu1C4KhEh9eWL8ve1VQDCWNYzlBponwR8Lp92sdqR4iOF9M/1L3S44wJ5Me@vpBOGbvkuoA@agbJJxEkWT37MnWPX85EAZ7agNJUhxaew8AsyCWfXuHSOraY9@vTe/ggO8tPnkfI18LfK5SOn3ECLBxB4y2aOKLmSXTW5KO@1X0ejTm/oa5oJ3i1EmaVGJQE6RPzyQwzGKRIaMCcK4/YPOZymVdhcjynLMZ7@3hQJVMdTw9G1UWg7IpPdi9oaJyc8vy9fOqTiw9K@Ucvnx7LkhKlhM4SvLK4dpHdUYvs7o5GPUkgH2U1TwWEHVRS@kNXDeUOsopkNGFSser0QxWI2Ylg8z//@nezmHd0lQHlebHOUAW7rDKAmqZulhZZTwWhhEurRErZkz8m6fCQ0sTqdJ3y0M9EL50JfwejEcL0OI45TS94Vb1jW/7WBcVKf/fSecimC5xCXsk36b0a3bHj@v7I1T2srfb7rRbZarc1H3iY0TDpb2XPaiyp@YP5PYij/hYXMIOOBJStW/YmTr7iJEXI@NAI7yRpx5mDyF@PYxPDtqkZNWURhl6BN61Av7L4UD8nknHVTNUE49HFNUX5H9LkqR7BAbRyKvVZu92GxEkeHT9@QiCFwmPTXMZweVrvg9PAYgO6n0bG6@zSO/QrFcaKODgU5Eg66N06KJXeFOjSwa2D3rDmly2hvKNfc4lNUSXgfqeCkHW019AvCPz6yZufnp8UBC6kw9Rt5SdoUbo3azabH7vzsLvT@/nB3YP9e057cPHg7s4DZ@/w2U675zzbYTt3d5y9nd7qww3WefHxgvzEQYfd9tjlUNMF@MsWsGJH31CBpi2nvQXllMyHeFkRKkL8KlMufMdK1cPCO5bzGMUfhMUVenjh22kdLA@Xt5a3l3eW3y6J0zqEL8Rpk@7WNnG/Jxd4b8g6JAfkDrlFbhOHfGvjuFstB8Yd4AgkUBnhkEPof2B/CY/bLezvLNVoctBCEpVxsr8cCxzluEPgdwdHIKdK/zvQN@3ZaYBt9Cr8438B)

Comment: I'm also starting to lose to [Python](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/236927/91340), as I predicted I would when I started doing actually complicated challenges in ErrLess :P

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 46 bytes

```ruby
->a,i{eval"a[#{i*B='],a['}]=a[#{i.rotate*B}]"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBRa8MgFIXf/RV36YNQbgNJuwwGdlDYa9d364NrLQvb0uCykmH87akaJbAXPff4nXNB/fv@N17YuNpKrI26ya9M8oWplztGBUpOrWDByPW1k51a7qzI7MgJcL5BKBDWCKVA4E6WborSuRv/INCT8S14jwgVwtPMVV6uA1ElovDElI188GKJD5QT6mXkU0MgpuzcmtYJ5NXcI4jIlTx9mEFqjfW5/0HVt@rUqfNAwM/MH/m3bM3QD/2qsARaXTcdZAvjMhbc1zjCAtsem4zAhacm8Z@EcDOWNsAL0OsnhWeg@7fD6wO1x8Z32PEO)

Lambda: modifies *a* by *i* indexes,
constructs an expression like for example:
*a[1],a[2],a[3]=a[2],a[3],a[1]*
and evaluates it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 114 bytes

```
(\d+).*$
$&,$1
\d+(?=.*$)
$*
\d+(?<=((,)|.)*)(?=.*¶(1*,)*(?<-2>1)*(?(2)$),(1)*)(?<=(?=(?<-4>\d+,)*(\d+)).*)
$5
1G`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY0xDsJADAR7v8NCttlE8ZGjyiUln6AACQoaCkSZd/EAPnb4QrerGXtf9/fjea1Vzre99sbEO7BTNFlKdCW2f5uKCHTt1XRD34@4QS1Il2ZvQZKyQnxTwl9Kg@Mc901sE7ERLzP56VLrAEfCASMyjjREzj8) 0-indexed. Explanation:

```
(\d+).*$
$&,$1
```

Duplicate the first index and append it.

```
\d+(?=.*$)
$*
```

Convert all of the indices to unary.

```
\d+
```

Match an array element...

```
(?<=((,)|.)*)
```

... calculating its index...

```
(?=.*¶(1*,)*(?<-2>1)*(?(2)$),(1)*)
```

... where that index exists in the list of indices, capturing the next index...

```
(?<=(?=(?<-4>\d+,)*(\d+)).*)
```

... capture the array element at that index...

```
$5
```

... and replace the original element.

```
1G`
```

Delete the indices.

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 60 bytes

**Input**: values as arguments, indices on stdin separated by whitespace. 1-indexed.

```sh
b=(`<&0`)
for x;{((k=b[(I)$[++i]]))&&x=$@[b[k%$#b+1]];<<<$x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY1BCoMwFET3OcVAU/ODFGq0dmEC3fYMISApFYsLoXYRKp49jdrV/Hkzw/9OfexI0vT84BSiN9Tq7NxK1o1vhGYmGoy3dJfc5vnLOSmzLBh@s94OR37weeFco7XmYYn7qIACMVGlo4QSECsoBdsVFS6ocd14iTrxzeOfJq7WTuJpnZJqbwomZ9aBmwLrN8Wej36EMMYItsQf)

```sh
b=(`<&0`)  # split stdin on whitespace
for x;{    # for x (implicit 'in "$@"')
   ((k=b[(I)$[++i]])) &&  # If we find $x's index in the array $b
    x=$@[b[k%$#b+1]]      # then update $x to be the elemnt at index $k + 1 (wrapped)
    <<<$x                 # output the element $x
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 55 bytes

```
Prompt A,I
ʟA(ʟI(1→F
For(I,2,dim(ʟI
ʟA(ʟI(I→ʟA(ʟI(I-1
End
F→ʟA(ʟI(dim(ʟI
```

`ʟA` is manipulated in-place. Indexes are 1-based.

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 6 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⍜⊏(↻1)
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4o2c4oqPKOKGuzEpCgpmIFswIDEgMl0gWzQgMSAzIDJdCmYgWzAgMiA1XSBbMSAyIDMgNCA1IDYgN10KZiBbMSAzIDRdIFs1IDYgNyAxIDIgMyA0XQpmIFswIDJdIFszIDIgNiA0XQo=)

0-indexed.

```
⍜⊏(↻1)
⍜       # apply one function 'under' another
 ⊏      # at the given indices
  (↻1)  # rotate left by one
```